# How to list the properties of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

Say I create an object thus:

```
var myObject =
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"};
```

What is the best way to retrieve a list of the property names? i.e. I would like to end up with some variable 'keys' such that:

```
keys == ["ircEvent", "method", "regex"]
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but if you use underscore.js: `_.keys(myJSONObject)`

Comment: **TL;DR:** If you want enumerable properties only: `Object.keys(obj)` Sometimes you want non-enumerable properties as well. Make sure to remember this if you do! To get them, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413145/1599699

Answer (score 1223, accepted):

In modern browsers (IE9+, FF4+, Chrome5+, Opera12+, Safari5+) you can use the built in [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
```

The above has a full polyfill but a simplified version is:

```
var getKeys = function(obj){
   var keys = [];
   for(var key in obj){
      keys.push(key);
   }
   return keys;
}
```

Alternatively replace `var getKeys` with `Object.prototype.keys` to allow you to call `.keys()` on any object.  Extending the prototype has some side effects and I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: I would update again to the effect 'you might be tempted to do this to object prototype ... but don't!'

Comment: will anybody want to put light on, why is it not recommended to add functions to prototype of Object?

Comment: That's a whole different question on it's own, a quick search here on stackoverflow or on google will give you plenty to read

Comment: I tried this in Google Chrome 27: you can simply use `keys(myJsonObject)` without referencing `Object`.

Comment: The `for (var key in myObject) {...}` technique is useful for javascript runtimes outside of browsers and V8.  For example, when passing javascript map-reduce queries into Riak the `Object` object doesn't exist, so the `Object.keys` method isn't available.

Comment: the polyfill is far aways faster. 
http://jsperf.com/listing-javascript-properties

Comment: `Object.keys()` in ECMA 5.1. In near future it will be available anywhere!

Comment: @slashnick Your "simplified version" returns all properties in the object's prototype chain (as it is using a "for ... in"), whereas the (ECMAScript 5.1) `Object.keys` method only returns the object's own properties. I see it as an important distinction.

Comment: I agree with @MartinCarel . In my opinion, the answer should be edited to filter out properties using `hasOwnProperty` (since it's a simplified version probably don't need to include the enumeration bug workaround). That's basically what the original question is asking (contextually), and what the actual `Object.keys` function does

Answer (score 273):

As [slashnick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object#208020) pointed out, you can use the "for in" construct to iterate over an object for its attribute names. However you'll be iterating over all attribute names in the object's prototype chain. If you want to iterate **only** over the object's own attributes, you can make use of the [Object#hasOwnProperty()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method. Thus having the following.

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        /* useful code here */
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I had read this before slashnic's answer above. I just had to spend 15 minutes holding down the `esc` key because the object had about a million properties, most of them not used, and I had an alert on it.

Comment: Here's an excelent article on the subject by Zakas himself:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/27/determining-if-an-object-property-exists/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+nczonline+(NCZOnline+-+The+Official+Web+Site+of+Nicholas+C.+Zakas)

Comment: LOL @MarkHenderson - but next time, just kill the browser's process and restart it instead of wasting 15 minutes :)

Comment: A related function is obj.getOwnPropertyNames() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: @MarkHenderson Why won't you use console.log?

Comment: Beautiful, should've updated the picked answer with this instead of adding a new one though.

Answer (score 105):

As Sam Dutton answered, a new method for this very purpose has been introduced in ECMAScript 5th Edition.  `Object.keys()` will do what you want and is supported in [Firefox 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), Chrome 6, Safari 5 and [IE 9](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201201438/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/25/enhanced-scripting-in-ie9-ecmascript-5-support-and-more.aspx).

You can also very easily implement the method in browsers that don't support it.  However, some of the implementations out there aren't fully compatible with Internet Explorer.  Here's a more compatible solution:

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || (function () {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !{toString:null}.propertyIsEnumerable("toString"),
        DontEnums = [ 
            'toString', 'toLocaleString', 'valueOf', 'hasOwnProperty',
            'isPrototypeOf', 'propertyIsEnumerable', 'constructor'
        ],
        DontEnumsLength = DontEnums.length;
        
    return function (o) {
        if (typeof o != "object" && typeof o != "function" || o === null)
            throw new TypeError("Object.keys called on a non-object");
    
        var result = [];
        for (var name in o) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(o, name))
                result.push(name);
        }
    
        if (hasDontEnumBug) {
            for (var i = 0; i < DontEnumsLength; i++) {
                if (hasOwnProperty.call(o, DontEnums[i]))
                    result.push(DontEnums[i]);
            }   
        }
    
        return result;
    };
})();
```

Note that the currently accepted answer doesn't include a check for *hasOwnProperty()* and will return properties that are inherited through the prototype chain.  It also doesn't account for the famous DontEnum bug in Internet Explorer where non-enumerable properties on the prototype chain cause locally declared properties with the same name to inherit their DontEnum attribute.

Implementing *Object.keys()* will give you a more robust solution.

**EDIT:** following a recent discussion with [kangax](http://perfectionkills.com), a well-known contributor to Prototype, I implemented the workaround for the DontEnum bug based on code for his `Object.forIn()` function found [here](http://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/experimental/object.for_in.js#L18).

Comment: Great answer, I think the accepted answer remains the most performant accurate solution, assuming that it is always a JSON dict. This is certainly the one to use elsewhere.

Comment: @David Caunt: Thanks :-) Unfortunately, the accepted answer would still fall foul of the DontEnum bug and you never know what JSON object might have a string like "valueOf" or "constructor" as one of its keys.  It will also iterate over extensions to `Object.prototype`. It's often the case, though, that shorter code looks significantly more appealing than larger, more robust code, but the point of this answer is to use ECMAScript 5th's `Object.keys()`, which can be implemented in browsers that don't support it using this code.  The native version would be even more performant than this.

Comment: Good point - you're right about the bug. I hope any good developer would test for the native methods ahead of using their own implementations.

Comment: Very nice, Andy :) I would just like to remind — no one seems to mention in this thread — that ES5 `Object.keys` only returns an array of strings corresponding to **enumerable** properties of an object. This might not be crucial when working with native (user-defined) objects, but should be very much visible with host objects (although unspecified host objects behavior is a separate — painful — story). To enumerate over ALL (including non-enumerable) properties, ES5 provides `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` (see its support in my compat. table — http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

Comment: I've integrated this solution into es5-shim http://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js#L390

Comment: @Kris: that's great, thanks for crediting :-) @kangax: yes, that's definitely worth mentioning and just reminded me of a piece of code I need to update, thanks :-)

Comment: Of course this still only works for `Object`. If you did something silly like putting a shadowing `getFullYear` property on a `Date` instance this would still fail to make that enumerable. To get around that you'd have to have a much longer list of all IE<9 native properties, and check every one with both `hasOwnProperty` and `propertyIsEnumerable`. Not much fun.

Comment: @bobince: not much fun, indeed!  Hopefully, this will tide us over until IE<9 is a distant memory :-)

Comment: Can someone explain why this is implemented as `Object.keys(stuff)` and not `stuff.keys()`?

Comment: @mblase75: rather than explain it here, you can read a discussion about it from the es-discuss mailing list, starting [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/jsmentors@googlegroups.com/msg01813.html).

Comment: @Kiquenet: yes, unfortunately the blog got lost to the ether when I left a previous job that included the hosting... sorry about that!

Comment: http://ww1.whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/a-safer-object-keys-compatibility-implementation not found, maybe found in ***archive.org*** ?

Answer (score 43):

Note that Object.keys and other ECMAScript 5 methods are supported by Firefox 4, Chrome 6, Safari 5, IE 9 and above.

For example:

```
var o = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}; 
alert(Object.keys(o));
```

[ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)

[Description of new methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20191202030643if_/http://markcaudill.com/2009/04/javascript-new-features-ecma5/)

Comment: Also check out keys() in the console for Chrome Dev Tools, Firebug, etc.

Comment: ***http://markcaudill.com/index.php/2009/04/javascript-new-features-ecma5/ not found***

Answer (score 36):

**`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`**

This function also shows non-enumerable properties in addition to those shown by `Object.keys(obj)`.

In JS, every property has a few properties, including a boolean `enumerable`.

In general, non-enumerable properties are more "internalish" and less often used, but it is insightful to look into them sometimes to see what is really going on.

Example:

```js
var o = Object.create({base:0})
Object.defineProperty(o, 'yes', {enumerable: true})
Object.defineProperty(o, 'not', {enumerable: false})

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o))
// [ 'yes', 'not' ]

console.log(Object.keys(o))
// [ 'yes' ]

for (var x in o)
    console.log(x)
// yes, base
```

Also note how:

- `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.keys` *don't* go up the prototype chain to find `base`
- `for in` does

More about the prototype chain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877420/895245

Answer (score 17):

I'm a huge fan of the dump function.

[Ajaxian » JavaScript Variable Dump in Coldfusion](https://web.archive.org/web/20070106184601/http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-variable-dump-in-coldfusion)

[Download the dump function](https://web.archive.org/web/20070106084136/http://www.netgrow.com.au/assets/files/dump/dump.zip)

[image]

Comment: +1 because I got here in the intention of building something similar (albeit not as good).

Comment: _http://www.netgrow.com.au/assets/files/dump/dump.zip not found_ ***How can I download dump javascript?***

Comment: @Kiquenet every time I wanted to build something like this I settle for the regular object inspector, if you want that rendered in HTML there's things like [npm modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-object-inspector). Frankly what got me stuck is I wanted something better than what's on that image but never managed to conceptualize it. It's shitty to browse objects in the inspector but heuristics to try and deduce meaning from arbitrary objects (e.g., sort out arrays of objects into tables with columns) not always works in practice.

Comment: What's about ***Pretty Print Javascript*** _`https://j11y.io/demos/prettyprint/`_ ?

Answer (score 15):

Could do it with jQuery as follows:

```
var objectKeys = $.map(object, function(value, key) {
  return key;
});
```

Answer (score 10):

if you are trying to get the elements only but not the functions then this code can help you

```
this.getKeys = function() {

    var keys = new Array();
    for(var key in this) {

        if( typeof this[key] !== 'function') {

            keys.push(key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

this is part of my implementation of the HashMap and I only want the keys, "this" is the hashmap object that contains the keys

Answer (score 10):

This will work in most browsers, even in IE8 , and no libraries of any sort are required.  var i is your key.

```
var myJSONObject =  {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"}; 
var keys=[];
for (var i in myJSONObject ) { keys.push(i); }
alert(keys);
```

Comment: Your answer seems similar to those already posted, anything else to add?

Answer (score 9):

Use `Reflect.ownKeys()`

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
Reflect.ownKeys(obj) // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

*Object.keys* and *Object.getOwnPropertyNames* cannot get **non-enumerable** properties. It's working even for *non-enumerable* properties.

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
obj[Symbol()] = 4;
Reflect.ownKeys(obj) // ["a", "b", "c", Symbol()]
```

Answer (score 8):

Under browsers supporting js 1.8:

```
[i for(i in obj)]
```

Comment: That's not javascript, is it? At least neither chrome nor node.js seem to be able to parse this. Looks a lot like python.

Answer (score 8):

Mozilla has [full implementation details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on how to do it in a browser where it isn't supported, if that helps:

```
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function () {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function (obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null) throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');

      var result = [];

      for (var prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) result.push(prop);
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (var i=0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) result.push(dontEnums[i]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  })();
}
```

You could include it however you'd like, but possibly in some kind of `extensions.js` file at the top of your script stack.

Comment: The MDN implementation is based on Andy E's, which was already given as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

With ES6 and later (ECMAScript 2015), you can get all properties like this:

```
let keys = Object.keys(myObject);
```

And if you wanna list out all values:

```
let values = Object.keys(myObject).map(key => myObject[key]);
```

Comment: ` let valudes = Object.values(myObject)` , should also work.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the accepted answer.

If the Object has properties you want to call say .properties() try!

```
var keys = Object.keys(myJSONObject);

for (var j=0; j < keys.length; j++) {
  Object[keys[j]].properties();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I use *underscore.js* in almost every project, I would use the [`keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys) function:

```
var obj = {name: 'gach', hello: 'world'};
console.log(_.keys(obj));
```

The output of that will be:

```
['name', 'hello']
```

Comment: It's a toolset library for often used javascript functionality: http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 4):

IE does not support for(i in obj) for native properties. Here is a list of all the props I could find.

It seems stackoverflow does some stupid filtering.

The list is available at the bottom of this google group post:-
https://groups.google.com/group/hackvertor/browse_thread/thread/a9ba81ca642a63e0

Answer (score 4):

A lot of answers here... This is my 2 cents.

I needed something to print out all the JSON attributes, even the ones with sub-objects or arrays (parent name included).

So - For this JSON:

```
mylittleJson = {
  "one": "blah",
  "two": {
      "twoone": "",
      "twotwo": "",
      "twothree": ['blah', 'blah']
  },
  "three": ""
}
```

It'd print this:

```
.one
.two.twoone
.two.twotwo
.two.twothree
.three
```

Here is function

```js
function listatts(parent, currentJson){
   var attList = []
   if (typeof currentJson !== 'object' || currentJson == undefined || currentJson.length > 0) {
      return
   }
   for(var attributename in currentJson){
       if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(currentJson, attributename)) {
           childAtts = listatts(parent + "." + attributename, currentJson[attributename])
           if (childAtts != undefined && childAtts.length > 0)
               attList = [...attList, ...childAtts]
           else 
               attList.push(parent + "." + attributename)
       }
   }
   return attList
}

mylittleJson = {
  "one": "blah",
  "two": {
      "twoone": "",
      "twotwo": "",
      "twothree": ['blah', 'blah']
  },
  "three": ""
}

console.log(listatts("", mylittleJson));
```

Hope it helps too.

Answer (score 1):

The solution work on my cases and cross-browser:

```
var getKeys = function(obj) {
    var type = typeof  obj;
    var isObjectType = type === 'function' || type === 'object' || !!obj;

    // 1
    if(isObjectType) {
        return Object.keys(obj);
    }

    // 2
    var keys = [];
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            keys.push(i)
        }
    }
    if(keys.length) {
        return keys;
    }

    // 3 - bug for ie9 <
    var hasEnumbug = !{toString: null}.propertyIsEnumerable('toString');
    if(hasEnumbug) {
        var nonEnumerableProps = ['valueOf', 'isPrototypeOf', 'toString',
            'propertyIsEnumerable', 'hasOwnProperty', 'toLocaleString'];

        var nonEnumIdx = nonEnumerableProps.length;

        while (nonEnumIdx--) {
            var prop = nonEnumerableProps[nonEnumIdx];
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
                keys.push(prop);
            }
        }

    }

    return keys;
};
```