# How to list the functions/methods of a javascript object? (Is it even possible?)

Tags: javascript, methods, scope, member-functions

This question is intentionally phrased like  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object).

I don't even know if this is possible, I remember vaguely hearing something about some properties not enumerable in JS.

Anyway, to cut a long story short: I'm developing something on a js framework for which I have no documentation and no easy access to the code, and it would greatly help to know what I can do with my objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var obj = { locaMethod: function() { alert("hello"); }, a: "b", c: 2 };
for(var p in obj)
{
    if(typeof obj[p] === "function") {
      // its a function if you get here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you include [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#object-functions) in your project, you can use `_.functions(yourObject)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to enumerate methods that are set directly on an object, e.g.:

```
var obj = { locaMethod: function() { alert("hello"); } };
```

But most methods will belong to the object's prototype, like so:

```
var Obj = function ObjClass() {};
Obj.prototype.inheritedMethod = function() { alert("hello"); };
var obj = new Obj();
```

So in that case you could discover the inherited methods by enumerating the properties of Obj.prototype.

Comment: This is the issue I am running into in practice. I'll get everything that is in my object, but not Obj.prototype, and then if I remember, put my code here as an answer. I think this is introspection. Is there another term for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
var obj = { locaMethod: function() { alert("hello"); }, a: "b", c: 2 };


for(var p in obj)
{
    console.log(p + ": " + obj[p]); //if you have installed Firebug.
}
```