# How to call a function from a exported module in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have defined in passport.js file a function called issueToken(user, done).
In server.js I have the following code:

```
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
```

In routes.js, I am trying to call the issueToken function:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
   ...
   passport.issueToken(req.user, function(err, token) {
   ...
   }
}
```

However it seems it is not the correct function call since it returns the following error:
TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.handle (/home/octavian/Desktop/node/login2/app/routes.js:54:12) (the line containing the issueToken function call above).

Any clues on what is the correct syntax for the call I'm trying to make?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's `issueToken` and not `issuedToken`?

Comment: should you define the require as a var? `var passport = require('./config/passport')(passport);`

Answer (score 0):

There is a zillion ways to export stuff from a Node module, but that is out of the scope of your question. You are using a pattern that is completely fine.

Your real problem is not the **export pattern** in the module itself or the **invocation pattern** in server.js, but the fact that the object `passport` that you are passing as an argument does not have an `issueToken` method, so that is what you should debug and figure out what's happening.

Comment: Well it should have that method, since I have defined it in passport.js.

Comment: Try to debug the prototype of the passport object, and i am sure you will find that it is not there :) You can list the functions on the object by using underscore _.functions(passport)

Comment: I'm trying to debug as you said, but I can't list the functions.....where exactly should I enter _.functions(passport), in the node debug console?

Comment: You need to use the underscore library to be able to do that or see some alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352997/how-to-list-the-functions-methods-of-a-javascript-object-is-it-even-possible