# Get all keys of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I was wondering if there was a quick way to extract keys of associative array into an array, or comma-separated list using JavaScript (jQuery is ok).

```
options = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
```

Result should be the array:

```
["key1", "key2"]
```

or just a string:

```
"key1, key2"
```

Comment: I think you meant `["key1","key2"]` not `{"key1","key2"}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list the properties of a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: It is. Too bad array is never mentioned there.

Comment: That's because there's no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript.  What you call an associative array is an object with a list of properties (hence, *how to list the properties of a javascript object*). That's also why the native method to list the keys resides on the `Object` object - *Object.keys()*.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can easily get an array of them via a `for` loop, for example:

```
var keys = [];
for(var key in options) {
  if(options.hasOwnProperty(key)) { //to be safe
    keys.push(key);
  }
}
```

Then use `keys` how you want, for example:

```
var keyString = keys.join(", ");
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Tr6dH/). The [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) check is to be safe, in case anyone messed with the object prototype and such.

Answer (score 29):

```
options = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
keys = Object.keys(options);
```

Comment: Please note that this is not supported by IE8 and below, currently 7.3% of worldwide browsers.

Comment: IE8 and below are now now about 1% of worldwide browsers.

Answer (score 5):

A jQuery way of doing it:

```
var keys = [];
options = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
$.each(options, function(key, value) { keys.push(key) })
console.log(keys)
```

Comment: you can also use
keys[keys.length] = key;
to be IE safe

Answer (score 3):

Most of the major browsers have this functionality built-in now, the method is [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var keys = Object.keys(options);
//-> ["key1", "key2"]
```

You can also use a little snippet to implement this in browsers that don't support it:

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || (function () {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

    return function (o) {
        if (typeof o != "object" && typeof o != "function" || o === null)
            throw new TypeError("Object.keys called on a non-object");

        var result = [];
        for (var name in o) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(o, name))
                result.push(name);
        }

        return result;
    };
})();
```

That snippet works much the same as the one in Nick Craver's example with 2 exceptions:

- It will throw a meaningful TypeError if you pass anything other than an Object in (or "associative array", if you like).
- It will work around an annoying DOM-related issue in Internet Explorer where collections don't have the `hasOwnProperty` method.

This (and the other answers here) doesn't work around an IE enumeration bug, however.  You can find more information and a partial work around for that on [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object/3937321#3937321).

Answer (score 2):

You can now use

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

to get an array consisting of the available keys in an object. [Mozilla has usage and availability information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each()` in jQuery:

```
function keyArray(obj) {
  var rv = [];
  $.each(options, function(key) { rv.push(key); });
  return rv;
}
```

then

```
var keys = keyArray(options);
```

gives you `["key1", "key2"]` as an array, which you could `join` to get a string.

Comment: The reason I don't advocate doing it this way is it's not safe, for example if anything's on the prototype, it'll appear in the list as well.  jQuery doesn't do a `hasOwnProperty()` check internally, see what I mean here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TJDCV/

Comment: oh well that's a good point - personally the lack of functional tools like that (that work "right") is the thing I miss most about Prototype, and I acknowledge that those things in Prototype are also the source of its biggest problems :-)

Comment: I guess that if there were a solid utility to convert an object to an array of key/value pairs (as 2-element arrays), plus a `.zip()` function, you could go a long way ...