# How to get all properties values of a JavaScript Object (without knowing the keys)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If there is a JavaScript object:

```
var objects={...};
```

Suppose, it has more than 50 properties, without knowing the property names (that's without knowing the 'keys') how to get each property value in a loop?

Comment: Note to readers: dont' miss the very insightful [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16643074/641451)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 514, accepted):

By using a simple `for..in` loop:

```
for(var key in objects) {
    var value = objects[key];
}
```

Comment: Be careful about the properties of the prototype object being inherited. See: hasOwnProperty()

Comment: **If you are reading this answer, you should _definitely_ read [the other one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16643074/641451)**

Comment: If you're reading this answer and you might be possibly dealing with strings, you should definitely punch javascript in the face.

Comment: If you read the above answer and want to punch JavaScript in the face, try [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Comment: Should probably point out that this will NOT include properties which have their `enumerable` flag set to false.  This - among other things - means you won't iterate over any class methods, but you will iterate over methods created in other ways.

Answer (score 1159):

Depending on which browsers you have to support, this can be done in a number of ways. The overwhelming majority of browsers in the wild support ECMAScript 5 (ES5), but be warned that many of the examples below use `Object.keys`, which is not available in IE < 9. See the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/).

## ECMAScript 3+

If you have to support older versions of IE, then this is the option for you:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
        var val = obj[key];
        // use val
    }
}
```

The nested `if` makes sure that you don't enumerate over properties in the prototype chain of the object (which is the behaviour you almost certainly want). You must use

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key) // ok
```

rather than

```
obj.hasOwnProperty(key) // bad
```

because ECMAScript 5+ allows you to create prototypeless objects with `Object.create(null)`, and these objects will not have the `hasOwnProperty` method. Naughty code might also produce objects which override the `hasOwnProperty` method.

## ECMAScript 5+

You can use these methods in any browser that supports ECMAScript 5 and above. These get values from an object and avoid enumerating over the prototype chain. Where `obj` is your object:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var val = obj[keys[i]];
    // use val
}
```

If you want something a little more compact or you want to be careful with functions in loops, then `Array.prototype.forEach` is your friend:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    var val = obj[key];
    // use val
});
```

The next method builds an array containing the values of an object. This is convenient for looping over.

```
var vals = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return obj[key];
});

// use vals array
```

If you want to make those using `Object.keys` safe against `null` (as `for-in` is), then you can do `Object.keys(obj || {})...`.

`Object.keys` returns *enumerable* properties. For iterating over simple objects, this is usually sufficient. If you have something with non-enumerable properties that you need to work with, you may use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` in place of `Object.keys`.

## ECMAScript 2015+ (A.K.A. ES6)

Arrays are easier to iterate with ECMAScript 2015. You can use this to your advantage when working with values one-by–one in a loop:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const val = obj[key];
    // use val
}
```

Using ECMAScript 2015 fat-arrow functions, mapping the object to an array of values becomes a one-liner:

```
const vals = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);

// use vals array
```

ECMAScript 2015 introduces `Symbol`, instances of which may be used as property names. To get the symbols of an object to enumerate over, use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` (this function is why `Symbol` *can't* be used to make private properties). The new `Reflect` API from ECMAScript 2015 provides `Reflect.ownKeys`, which returns a list of property names (including non-enumerable ones) and symbols.

### Array comprehensions (do not attempt to use)

Array comprehensions were **removed** from ECMAScript 6 before publication. Prior to their removal, a solution would have looked like:

```
const vals = [for (key of Object.keys(obj)) obj[key]];

// use vals array
```

## ECMAScript 2017+

ECMAScript 2016 adds features which do not impact this subject. The ECMAScript 2017 specification adds `Object.values` and `Object.entries`. Both return arrays (which will be surprising to some given the analogy with `Array.entries`). `Object.values` can be used as is or with a `for-of` loop.

```
const values = Object.values(obj);

// use values array or:

for (const val of Object.values(obj)) {
    // use val
}
```

If you want to use both the key and the value, then `Object.entries` is for you. It produces an array filled with `[key, value]` pairs. You can use this as is, or (note also the ECMAScript 2015 destructuring assignment) in a `for-of` loop:

```
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    // use key and val
}
```

## `Object.values` shim

Finally, as noted in the comments and by teh_senaus in another answer, it may be worth using one of these as a shim. Don't worry, the following does not change the prototype, it just adds a method to `Object` (which is much less dangerous). Using fat-arrow functions, this can be done in one line too:

```
Object.values = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
```

which you can now use like

```
// ['one', 'two', 'three']
var values = Object.values({ a: 'one', b: 'two', c: 'three' });
```

If you want to avoid shimming when a native `Object.values` exists, then you can do:

```
Object.values = Object.values || (obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]));
```

## Finally...

Be aware of the browsers/versions you need to support. The above are correct where the methods or language features are implemented. For example, support for ECMAScript 2015 was switched off by default in V8 until recently, which powered browsers such as Chrome. Features from ECMAScript 2015 should be be avoided until the browsers you intend to support implement the features that you need. If you use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code to ECMAScript 5, then you have access to all the features in this answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted (or atleast more upvoted) answer as the accepted one is incomplete (@olive points this out).

Comment: It's a shame that of all the so-called tricks, we still need to mention `obj` twice. I guess creating a helper function is unavoidable? Something like values(obj).

Comment: Any of these methods can be used as a shim. For example:
`Object.values = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);`

Comment: To the downvoter, please leave a comment. I'll do my best to address criticism, but I can't do anything without knowing what the issue was.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but perhaps it was because your code generates an " Unexpected token > " syntax error.

Comment: The ECMA 5 solutions should work in all modern browsers. ECMA 6 has not yet been finalised, and support is preliminary in all browsers. In Chrome, ECMA 6 is partially implemented but disabled. In Firefox, the support is better but the array comprehension are wrong (as mentioned). I thought my use of the future tense would imply this. @JacekLampart, which solution gave you the error?

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. Also note that there are several ways to compile ES6 to ES5 so you can begin using arrow functions now. TypeScript does this for example.

Comment: I can't imagine why we have to wait for ES2017 to get an Object.values() method.

Comment: *"Finally, as noted in the comments and by teh_senaus in another answer, it may be worth using one of these as a shim. Don't worry, the following does not change the prototype, it just adds a method to Object (which is much less dangerous)."* Even so, isn't it better to check `if (!Object.values)` before overriding the possibly more efficient engine implementation?

Comment: It depends. If you prefer consistency, then you might want to always replace the method. I'll update to make it clearer though. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the `Object.keys(..).map(..)` approach wind up iterating over an object twice? Once to convert the keys to an array and then again during the `.map`? It seems that performance-minded people would actually prefer the `for key in obj | if (hasOwnProperty)` approach, as this iterates a single time.

Comment: @kevlarr in principle you're right, although my understanding is that none of the major JS engines do it in JS, opting to use underlying access to their implementations of Object to collect keys. A few non-scientific tests show that filtered for-in performs consistently worse than using Object.keys and iterating over the result. Of course, it's always worth checking the perf of both when coding a hot path!

Comment: @qubyte Ah fascinating, I haven't seen any numbers showing this would actually be more efficient. I can imagine there could be some magic under the hood, but given that most JS environments don't have any implementations of iterators/generators/streams, I assumed this would not already have been optimized for the `.keys(..).map(..)` technique

Comment: @kevlarr JS does in fact implement iterators/generators, but since Object.keys predates these it always returns an array. The question is really whether it is slower to collect keys and then iterate over them or to iterate and filter over uncollected keys. It seems like the overhead of collecting them is relatively small compared with looping over entries in JS land.

Comment: @qubyte "ECMAScript specifies iterators/generators, but they still aren't widely supported in most runtimes" was what I meant... I honestly am curious about the implementation of `Object.keys` and whether it needs to iterate over *all* object properties (which if it does is no better than a `for` loop).

If it doesn't, then yeah I think you're completely right - the overhead of collecting them and then iterating over them a *second time* is still probably way less than looping a single time over the entire prototype chain.

Comment: Oh whoops, I stand corrected.. Generators are pretty widely supported after all, just not in IE. (Would link to doc if stack overflow allowed links with * in them)

Comment: Probably worth noting that all of these _only_ get you enumerable properties, which can matter quite a bit.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a reusable function for getting the values into an array. It takes prototypes into account too.

```
Object.values = function (obj) {
    var vals = [];
    for( var key in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            vals.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return vals;
}
```

Comment: Modifying `Object` isn't much of a problem (`Object.keys` is a common shim), you are probably thinking of modifying the Object prototype.

Comment: Why would you need to test with `hasOwnProperty()`? How would the key be iterated over within the loop of that object hasn't got the property?

Comment: Google it @thomas, it's important. It might have properties from its prototype chain.

Answer (score 29):

If you have access to Underscore.js, you can use the [`_.values`](http://underscorejs.org/#values) function like this:

```
_.values({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3}); // return [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @MathieuAmiot -- care to explain?

Comment: lodash is an api-compatible replacement for underscore, a (way) faster one.

Comment: @Paden here's a related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore

Comment: lodash is unnecessary for this and will bloat your code base

Answer (score 15):

ES5 [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
Object.keys(a).map(function(key){ return a[key] });
// result: [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I would say that this is one of the cleanest solutions.

Comment: I dont know, why is this down voted. This is the easiest and purest solution in js without using any libraries or any other utilities.

Comment: @sanjeevshetty `Object.values` is the easier solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you really want an array of Values, I find this cleaner than building an array with a for ... in loop.

ECMA 5.1+

```
function values(o) { return Object.keys(o).map(function(k){return o[k]}) }
```

It's worth noting that in most cases you don't really need an array of values, it will be faster to do this:

```
for(var k in o) something(o[k]);
```

This iterates over the keys of the Object o. In each iteration k is set to a key of o.

Answer (score 9):

`const myObj = { a:1, b:2, c:3 }`

Get all values:

- the shortest way:

  - `const myValues = Object.values(myObj)`
- `const myValues = Object.keys(myObj).map(key => myObj[key])`

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through the keys:

```
foo = {one:1, two:2, three:3};
for (key in foo){
    console.log("foo["+ key +"]="+ foo[key]);
}
```

will output:

```
foo[one]=1
foo[two]=2
foo[three]=3
```

Comment: You also need to check `hasOwnProperty()' if you want to avoid inherited attributes.

Answer (score 5):

ECMA2017 onwards:

`Object.values(obj)` will fetch you all the property values as an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: Should note that this will NOT return inherited properties.

Answer (score 5):

The question doesn't specify whether wanting inherited and non-enumerable properties also.

There is [a question for getting everything, inherited properties and non-enumerable properties also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object), that Google cannot easily find.

If we are to get all inherited and non-enumerable properties, my solution for that is:

```
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
    let result = new Set();
    while (obj) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(p => result.add(p));
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return [...result];
}
```

And then iterate over them, just use a for-of loop:

```js
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  let result = new Set();
  while (obj) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(p => result.add(p));
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  return [...result];
}

let obj = {
  abc: 123,
  xyz: 1.234,
  foobar: "hello"
};

for (p of getAllPropertyNames(obj)) console.log(p);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those early adapting people on the CofeeScript era, here's another equivalent for it.

```
val for key,val of objects
```

Which may be better than this because the `objects` can be reduced to be typed again and decreased readability.

```
objects[key] for key of objects
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently - as I recently learned - this is the fastest way to do it:

```
var objs = {...};
var objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0, objLen = objKeys.length; i < objLen; i++) {
    // do whatever in here
    var obj = objs[objKeys[i]];
}
```

Comment: can you put a codepen or jsfiddle of an example of this? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use a polyfill like:

```
if(!Object.values){Object.values=obj=>Object.keys(obj).map(key=>obj[key])}
```

then use

```
Object.values(my_object)
```

3) profit!

Answer (score 3):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// expected output:
// "a: somestring"
// "b: 42"
// order is not guaranteed
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm a little late but here's a **shim** for the new firefox 47 `Object.values` method

```
Object.prototype.values = Object.prototype.values || function(obj) {
  return this.keys(obj).map(function(key){
    return obj[key];
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.entries do it in better way.

```js
  var dataObject = {"a":{"title":"shop"}, "b":{"title":"home"}}
 
   Object.entries(dataObject).map(itemArray => { 
     console.log("key=", itemArray[0], "value=", itemArray[1])
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:  `Object.values()`, we pass in an object as an argument and receive an array of the values as a return value.

This returns an array of a given object own enumerable property values. You will get the same values as by using the `for in` loop but without the properties on the Prototype. This example will probably make things clearer:

```js
function person (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

person.prototype.age = 5;

let dude = new person('dude');

for(let prop in dude) {
  console.log(dude[prop]);     // for in still shows age because this is on the prototype
}                              // we can use hasOwnProperty but this is not very elegant

// ES6 + 
console.log(Object.values(dude));
// very concise and we don't show props on prototype
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest option is like this:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key, index) {
  var value = data[key];
  console.log(key, index, value);
});
```

For example, a runnable code is added here:

```js
const user = {
    name: 'Alex',
    age: 30,
};

Object.keys(user).forEach(function (key, index) {
  var value = user[key];
  console.log(key, index, value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function similar to PHP's array_values()

```
function array_values(input) {
  var output = [], key = '';
  for ( key in input ) { output[output.length] = input[key]; }
  return output;
}
```

Here's how to get the object's values if you're using ES6 or higher:

```
Array.from(values(obj));
```

Comment: For some reason values() is working in Chrome and Firefox, but not on iojs/node.

Answer (score 0):

## Compatible with ES7 even some browsers do not support it yet

Since , `Object.values(<object>)` will be built-in in **[ES7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** &

Until waiting all browsers to support it , you could wrap it inside a function :

```
Object.vals=(o)=>(Object.values)?Object.values(o):Object.keys(o).map((k)=>o[k])
```

Then :

```
Object.vals({lastname:'T',firstname:'A'})
 // ['T','A']
```

#### Once browsers become compatible with ES7, you will not have to change anything in your code.

Answer (score 0):

*we can fetch data using three methods below*

**Use map function**

```
data.map( item => { console.log(item) }
```

**Use for loop**

```
for( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   console.log(item);
}
```

**Use for in loop**

```
for(key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       const value = data[key];
       console.log(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var objects={...}; this.getAllvalues = function () {
        var vls = [];
        for (var key in objects) {
            vls.push(objects[key]);
        }
        return vls;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

in **ECMAScript5** use

```
 keys = Object.keys(object);
```

Otherwise if you're browser does not support it, use the well-known `for..in loop`

```
for (key in object) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: The question was asking for the values, not the keys.

Comment: @zachelrath You're right. - But this script is useful if you want to get the values because when you know the keys you are able to use `object[key]` to get the values in a loop.

Comment: @fridojet But that can be done with `for..in` (and hasOwnProperty) so it doesn't really gain anything .. I wish that ECMAScript 5th defined `Object.pairs` (and `Object.items` for `[[key, value], ..]`), but alas, it does not.

Answer (score -9):

Now I use [Dojo Toolkit](https://dojotoolkit.org/) because older browsers do not support `Object.values`.

```
require(['dojox/lang/functional/object'], function(Object) {
    var obj = { key1: '1', key2: '2', key3: '3' };
    var values = Object.values(obj);
    console.log(values);
});
```

Output :

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the array is not correct. You have an array of strings instead of an array of numbers.

Answer (score -11):

use

```
console.log(variable)
```

and if you using google chrome open Console by using Ctrl+Shift+j

Goto >> Console