# Get value from object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get value from days2-Tuesday?

```
additionalData = {
    "days1":[{"Monday": 1, "Tuesday": 2, "Wednesday": 2, "Thursday": 2, "Friday": 2, "Saturday": 2, "Sunday": 2}], 
    "days2":[{"Monday": 12, "Tuesday": 2, "Wednesday": 2, "Thursday": 2, "Friday": 2, "Saturday": 2, "Sunday": 2}], 
    "days3":[{"Monday": 13, "Tuesday": 2, "Wednesday": 2, "Thursday": 2, "Friday": 2, "Saturday": 2, "Sunday": 2}], 
    "days4":[{"Monday": 14, "Tuesday": 2, "Wednesday": 2, "Thursday": 2, "Friday": 2, "Saturday": 2, "Sunday": 2}] 
};
```

Comment: Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) look this topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718473/get-key-and-value-of-object-in-javascript)

Comment: `additionalData.days2[0].Tuesday;`

Comment: Why do you have the objects in arrays, when they only contain 1 object? Anyway: `additionalData.days2[0].Tuesday`. This is not jQuery btw.

Comment: So why do you want to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 3):

You can access days2/Tuesday like this:

```
var tuesday = additionalData.days2[0].Tuesday;
```

The jQuery-version (but it does not make any sense to use that):

```
var tuesday = jQuery(additionalData.days2).get(0).Tuesday;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You didn't use jQuery! :)

Comment: How is that possible? :o `let the irony flow`

Comment: @Arg0n I'm pretty sure it's a joke ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm pretty sure mine was too, hence the `irony` part.

Comment: Well, just for the fun of it. We all learned something ;-)