# Javascript equivalent of Python's values() dictionary method

Tags: javascript

In Python I can use the `.values()` method to iterate over the *values* of a dictionary.

For example:

```
mydict = {'a': [3,5,6,43,3,6,3,],
          'b': [87,65,3,45,7,8],
          'c': [34,57,8,9,9,2],}
values = mydict.values():
```

Where `values` contains:

```
[
    [3,5,6,43,3,6,3,],
    [87,65,3,45,7,8],
    [34,57,8,9,9,2],
]
```

How can I get only the values of the dictionary in Javascript?

My original print example wasn't clear on what I'd like to do.  I only want a list/array of the values within the dictionary.

I realize I can cycle through the list and create a new list of the values, but is there a better way?

Comment: @Oriol I disagree with this closure. This one specifically asks about returning to an array. Granted, not all the answers address that properly. The other question wants to access it from a loop. I think this is shown by the fact that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28414954/3187556) applies to this question but not the target.

Comment: @Scimonster The [most upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16643074/1529630) in the other question answers this perfectly. It even includes a variation of your answer to this question. You can vote to reopen if you disagree, though.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

**Updated**
I've upvoted Adnan's answer as it was the first. I'm just posting a bit more details if it helps.

The [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop is what you are looking for -

```
var dictionary = {
    id:'value',
    idNext: 'value 2'
}

for (var key in dictionary){
    //key will be -> 'id'
    //dictionary[key] -> 'value'
}
```

To get all the keys in the `dictionary` object, you can `Object.keys(dictionary)`
This means, you can do the same thing in an array loop --

```
var keys = Object.keys(dictionary);
keys.forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key, dictionary[key]);
});
```

This proves especially handy when you want to filter keys without writing ugly `if..else` loops.

```
keys.filter(function(key){
    //return dictionary[key] % 2 === 0;
    //return !key.match(/regex/)
    // and so on
});
```

**Update** - 
To get all the values in the dictionary, currently there is no other way than to perform a loop. How you do the loop is a matter of choice though. Personally, I prefer

```
var dictionary = {
    a: [1,2,3, 4],
    b:[5,6,7]
}
var values = Object.keys(dictionary).map(function(key){
    return dictionary[key];
});
//will return [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7]]
```

Comment: Upvoting isn't about who's first. If the answer is helpful & useful then it's wroth upvoting, pretty much like yours xdazz's

Comment: Object.keys(dictionary).map can be made prettier in jQuery! Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/18063034/764463

Comment: @Temuz, http://needsmorejquery.com/

Comment: @mac9416 oh boy you really showed that 2013 comment who's boss!

Comment: @Temuz touché.  :-)

Comment: @mac9416, did someone really pay for level 2 domain name to host only a pair of static files?!

Comment: @ogurets folks be salty.

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw Money well spent I say; both on comedic and educational value :D thanks for sharing.  Every time I read jquery these days I hear that line from Butt Machine by That One Guy: "And just because we can, it doesn't mean we should"

Answer (score 40):

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) is available in Firefox 47 and Chrome 51, here's a one-line polyfill for other browsers:

```
Object.values = Object.values || function(o){return Object.keys(o).map(function(k){return o[k]})};
```

Answer (score 27):

With jQuery, there's a pretty one line version using $.map():

```
var dict = {1: 2, 3: 4};
var values = $.map(dict, function(value, key) { return value });
var keys = $.map(dict, function(value, key) { return key });
```

Comment: The most elegant solution

Answer (score 13):

Not trying to say that any of the other answers are wrong, but if you're not opposed to using an external library, [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#values) has a method for precisely this:

```
_.values({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
// returns [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
mydict = {'a': [3,5,6,43,3,6,3,],
          'b': [87,65,3,45,7,8],
          'c': [34,57,8,9,9,2]};
for (var key in mydict){
    alert(mydict[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In ES6, currently supported by default in Firefox and with flags in Chrome, you can do this:

```
a = {'a': [3,5,6,43,3,6,3,],
      'b': [87,65,3,45,7,8],
      'c': [34,57,8,9,9,2]}
values = [a[x] for (x in a)];
```

`values` will now be the expected array.

This is also useful for [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Removing the spaces around `for` cuts it down to 17 characters.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, you use `for..in` to loop the properties of an object.

```
var mydict = {
    'a': [3,5,6,43,3,6,3,],
    'b': [87,65,3,45,7,8],
    'c': [34,57,8,9,9,2]
 };

for (var key in mydict) {
  console.log(mydict[key]);
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` I forget about it every time, +1

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get only the values the use the follwing code:

```
 for(keys in mydict){
   var elements = mydict[keys];
   console.log(elements);
 }
```

you can get Individual elements by index value in elements array.