# get a list of values from a specific js object key

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary

I have a JavaScript object build as a list of dictionaries.
example of a possible data set:

```
object =
[
{'name':'abc', 'type':'manual', 'some_id':'d23d', 'assigned_items':['this1']},
{'name':'hef', 'type':'manual', 'some_id':'3hhs', 'assigned_items':['this2, this3']},
{'name':'kuy', 'type':'manual', 'some_id':'k7fd', 'assigned_items':['this4']},
]
```

I am trying to get a list of all the `assigned_items`, which will sometimes be more than one.
so the output I would like for this data set will be:

`result = ['this1', 'this2', 'this3', 'this4']`

I tried the answers explaind here, but it did not work

[Javascript equivalent of Python's values() dictionary method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734417/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-values-dictionary-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = [{'name':'abc', 'type':'manual', 'some_id':'d23d','assigned_items':['this1']},{'name':'hef', 'type':'manual', 'some_id':'3hhs', 'assigned_items':['this2', 'this3']},{'name':'kuy', 'type':'manual', 'some_id':'k7fd','assigned_items':['this4']},]

const res = input.flatMap(e => e.assigned_items)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: The inner array is not necessary `e => e.assigned_items`

Comment: @adiga thats true, updated. Thanks for notice.