# Access nested array for all elements in ES6/Javascript

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

How to access nested array of all elements of an array in ES6?
Eg

```
source = [
    {
       id: '1',
       list: ['a1','a2','a3']  
    },
   {
       id: '2',
       list: ['b1','b2']  
   }
]
```

i want an output `['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2]`

i'm doing this but its returning array with length 1, 0th element  `['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2]`.

```
source.map(x=>x.list).map(x=>x);
```

Comment: Use `Array.flatMap()` instead - `source.flatMap(x=>x.list)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get a list of values from a specific js object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598998/get-a-list-of-values-from-a-specific-js-object-key)