# create a array from the data's object, there is a better to make this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, methods

I have done this basic algoritm, for putting all the data of the object's attributes inside of a array, there is a better way of doing this, I am a beginner on **Javascript, thanks for the help.**

```
const datos = {
    nombre:"Kurosaki",
    apellido:"Ichigo",
    edad:20,
    altura:180,
    eresDesarrollador:false,
}

//Con este algoritmo se almacenan sin el uso de metodos los valores del objeto datos en un array
var i = 0
var array = []
for (const valor in datos) {
   
    array[i] = datos[valor] 
    i++;
}
console.log(array)// Output [ 'Kurosaki', 'Ichigo', 20, 180, false ]
```

I would like to know if exists a method() for improving this code, and make it shorter

Comment: Just do Object.values(datos)

Comment: no need for the `i` index, `const array = Object.values(datos);`

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method.

I got the answer from a similar post: [Javascript equivalent of Python's values() dictionary method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734417/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-values-dictionary-method). You have to scroll down a bit.

Edit: here's the original answer from the above post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23780751/21371665 I didn't originally know how to share that specific answer.