# jsons with different fields every time

Tags: javascript, json

I've been searching for an answer but couldn't find it.
I have a json like this:

```
followersperdate{
 'date2012-08-29': 16823,
 'date2012-07-09': 15571,
 'date2012-07-07': 15528,
 'date2012-06-25': 15237,
 'date2012-04-19': 13283,
 'date2012-03-16': 12999,
 etc.
}
```

and I want to get the values; but everytime I make the request, I recieve other dates. I don't know how to get the values.

I've tried with jsonpath but didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Comment: sorry for that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty trivial using DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com). This lib extends the global object JSON with the method "search". Using this method, you can search a JSON structure, regardless of depth for values. It returns an array with the matches (empty array if no matches were found).

To get acquainted with XPath, check out this valuable resource;
http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator

Check out this fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/DKuAQ/

```
var data = {
   "date2012-08-29": 16823,
   "date2012-07-09": 15571,
   "date2012-07-07": 15528,
   "date2012-06-25": 15237,
   "date2012-04-19": 13283,
   "date2012-03-16": 12999
  },
  res = JSON.search( data, '//*' ),
  str = '';

for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
   str += res[i] +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
```