# AngularJS create element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm newbie in angular.js. i want to create basic grid to learn angular.js. i create a blog application with angular.js but i want to learn more. i'm starting development to grid application. this grid will do crud operations dynamicliy.
i'm write this in html side;

```
< bar-table 
bar-list-action="'/json/customers.htm'" 
bar-delete-action="'/api/DeleteCustomer'" 
bar-update-action="'/api/UpdateCustomer'" / >
```

and js side;

```
barbarapp.directive("barTable", function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/customers.html',
        scope: {
            barSource: '=',
            barListAction: '=',
            barDeleteAction: '=',
            barUpdateAction: '=',
            barTemplateUrl: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var listAction = scope.barListAction;
            $http.get(listAction)
                .success(function (response) {
                    scope.rows = response.records;
                });

            scope.deleteAction = function (row) {
                //scope.barDeleteAction

            };
            scope.updateAction = function () {
                //scope.barUpdateAction
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and template;

```
< table class="table table-hover">
    < tr ng-repeat="row in rows" >
        < td >{{row.Id}}< /td >
        < td >{{row.Name}} < /td >
        < td >
            < input type="button" value="Sil" ng-click="deleteAction(row)" class="btn btn-danger" >
        </ td >
        < td >
            < input type="button" value="Güncelle" ng-click="updateAction(row)" class="btn btn-warning" >
        < /td >
    < /tr>
< /table >
```

My idea;
user define columns defination in html or if user undefine columns defination, my app. create dynamicly columns. but i don't know how to do this.
please show way me to user's define column or dynamicly create columns.
p.s: sory for my bad english.

Comment: Tip: You don't need to "escape" your HTML when posting it in code blocks on SO

Comment: Do you want to create a column for every key of a row?

Comment: yes, i want to create column for every key of a row. miichi's answer helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have a `columns` array in your scope as well, that lists the names of the properties used in your row object.  You can fill this columns array either by requiring the user to specify it as parameter of the directive or by using something like a `for..in` loop to get it from one of the row objects in rows (see also [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key) for other ways to get all properties of an object).  When you have this you could do something like

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="col in columns">
        {{row[col]}}
    </td>
    <!-- other td's for deleting etc. -->
</tr>
```

Letting the user specify the columns array might be more apt since it allows them to select only some columns and specify the order.