# Reading and parsing "bad" json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have data in the format

```
{
    "id1":["name1",10,20],
    "id2":["name2",12,20],
    "id3":["name3",14,21]
}
```

and am reading it in with

```
var dat;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        dat = data.items;
        console.log(dat);
    });
});
```

This is proving problematic to read into properly because I gather (please clarify if I'm wrong) this is a poor json format as it lacks field names.  Moreover the ':' seems to create something like a dictionary class and I'm not sure if that is preventing the resulting object from being iterable.  If I call it in the console (e.g. `dat[0]`) I get "undefined", but perhaps there is an additional jquery error here.

So the question is how read this in so the data is accessible/iterable?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't lack field names; the problem is that one of the field names is duplicated. Also, what `'.'` are you referring to?

Comment: Forgive me that's a typo the data has unique names. Have corrected

Comment: Okay. So what exactly is the problem? It parses fine for me. Note that there is no `"items"` attribute in the JSON structure. Could that be the problem with your code?

Comment: How to access the data in the resulting object. Calling `dat[0]` gives  'undefined'.  Nor does `dat.length` give anything, etc.

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/89uGj/

Comment: when in doubt, validate your json in jsonlint.com...passes fine there

Comment: Thanks. By "bad" I mean poorly structured, not invalid.  e.g. [http://jsfiddle.net/7kSkJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/7kSkJ/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the data format (after your edit), but you are trying to use a property `items` that doesn't exist.

You can loop through the items in the object, and access the values from each array:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  // key contains "id1", "id2", and "id3" for the iterations
  // value is the array
  var name = value[0]; // contains "name1", "name2", "name3"
  var num1 = value[1]; // contains 10, 12, 14
  var num2 = value[2]; // contains 20, 20, 21
});
```

Note: The order of items in an object is undefined, so you can get them in the order `"id1", "id2", "id3"` or any other order like `"id2", "id3", "id1"`. Different browsers will return them in different order.

Comment: This is spot on, thanks.  Slightly streamlined version with usable data object output: 
`dat = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) dat[dat.length] = {name:value[0], num1:value[1], num2:value[2]});`

Comment: @geotheory: Even more streamlined with the `map` method: `var dat = $.map(data, function(value, key) { return { name:value[0], num1:value[1], num2:value[2] }; });`. :)

Answer (score 0):

When JQuery calls the call-back the `data` parameter is the object that results from parsing the JSON. It doesn't have an `items` attribute. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            console.log("Key: " + key + "; value: " + val);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confused as to what data structure JSON follows.

JSON does follow a similar structure to a Dictionary. In JavaScript though, there is no `.items()` method (I assume that's what you meant with `data.items`) like there is in other languages like Python. When you write `data.property` it is equivalent to `data['property']`, just like getting the value of a key in a dictionary data structure.

On how to parse objects, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Enumerating_all_properties_of_an_object

You can find some descriptions of parsing JSON here as well [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key) if the other answers don't quite work for your case.

Comment: I meant Object Literal, but yes there are some minute differences between the two regardless -- I edited that out as that can be confusing, thanks!

Comment: Yes, JSON and object literal notation are similar but not the same. Certainly JSON and object literals themselves are basically unrelated, and JSON and Javascript objects are completely unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EHret/

few different ways to reach the data.

```
var data =  {
    "id1":["name1",10,20],
    "id2":["name2",12,20],
    "id3":["name3",14,21]
};

$("div").append(data["id1"] + "<br />");
$("div").append(data["id2"][0] + "<br />");
$("div").append(data["id2"][1] + "<br />");
$("div").append(data["id2"][2] + "<br />");

$.each(data, function(index, val){
    $("div").append(index + " : " + val + "<br />");
    $.each(val, function(key, value){
        $("div").append(key + " : " + value + "<br />");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this method necessitates prior knowledge of the id values.

Comment: did you check the loops at the bottom by themselves? there is no prior knowledge in those each loops. It breaks it a part into each value based on the data.

Comment: I confess not. Thanks for clarifying