# Turn properties of object into a comma-separated list?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an object like this:

```
var person = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",
  phone: "253 689 4555"
}
```

I want:

```
John,Smith,253 689 4555
```

Is there some easy way?

If possible, could you please provide **an example where I can also define the separator?**

Comment: As a reference, this is in essence just [getting the object values as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7306669/1218980) and joining them with `join`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use this one-liner in modern browsers

```
Object.keys(person).map(function(k){return person[k]}).join(",");
```

Comment: Yes, until you include polyfills for Object.keys and Array.map :/

Comment: Can I be sure with list order?

Comment: Sweet, thanks a bunch! Just a tip, great answers explain why and provide documentation links :) Anyway, ++1

Comment: This is rather old now, but what about just doing: Object.values(person).join(',')

Comment: How do we maintain the order of value?

Answer (score 26):

This code will be useful when you want to extract some property values from an array of objects as comma separated string.

```
    var arrayObjects = [
  {
    property1: "A",
    property2: "1"
  },
  {
    property1: "B",
    property2: "2"
  },
  {
    property1: "C",
    property2: "3"
  }
];

Array.prototype.map.call(arrayObjects, function(item) { return item.property1; }).join(",");
```

**Output** - "A,B,C"

Comment: Dear Sachin Can you please explain this lines of code Array.prototype.map.call(arrayObjects, function(item) { return item.property1; }).join(",");

Comment: just have a look at this https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/explain-array-prototype-map-call/165936 - @DEEPADHIYA

Comment: @Sachin Gaur What just I exactly want Thank's lot.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Javascript, but `arrayObjects.map(x => x.property1).join(",")` seems to return the same result.

Comment: @DavidS ah yes, this makes sense. Good catch. Was overcomplicating it in my head.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simpler one liner.  It uses the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method instead of Object.keys

```
Object.values(obj).join(",");
```

Comment: ++ for one-liner

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
var key,
  person = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Smith",
    phone: "253 689 4555"
  },
  array = [];

for ( key in person ) {
  if ( person.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    array.push( person[ key ] );
  }
}

console.log( array.join( ',' ) );
```

or in function style:

```
var
  getValues = function ( obj ) {
    var key,
      array = [];

    for ( key in obj ) {
      if ( obj .hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
        array.push( obj [ key ] );
      }
    }

    return obj.join( ',' );
  };

var person = {
      name: "John",
      surname: "Smith",
      phone: "253 689 4555"
    };

console.log( getValues( person ) );
```

Answer (score 7):

Write a function like this:

```
function toCSV(obj, separator) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }

    return arr.join(separator || ",");
}
```

And then you can call it like:

```
toCSV(person, "|"); // returns "John|Smith|253 689 4555"
```

or

```
toCSV(person); // returns "John,Smith,253 689 4555"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var arr = [
    {
        key_1: "A",
        key_2: "1"
    },
    {
        key_1: "B",
        key_2: "2"
    },
    {
        key_1: "C",
        key_2: "3"
    }
];

var CSVOf_arr = arr.map((item) => { return item.key_1 }).join(',')

console.log('Comma seprated values of arr', CSVOf_arr)
```

**OUTPUT: A,B,C**

Comment: Even though this isn't quite what the OP wanted, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @jbobbins  Welcome ✌️ ;)

Answer (score 3):

The [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values. It can be used to convert object properties to an array which can then be joined using [.join(separator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create the required string with separator defined in join function. But this will cause empty values to be joined as well. So for an object as

```
var person = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",
  phone: ""
}
```

output for

```
Object.values(person).join(',')
```

will be

> John,Smith,

with an additional "," at the end. To avoid this [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can be used  to remove empty elements from array and then use join on filtered array.

```
Object.values(person).filter(Boolean).join(',')
```

will output

> John,Smith

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this library - [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). It gives you really helpful methods and works across browsers.

Here you can do it like this -

```
_.values(person).join(",")
```

or

```
_.values(person).join("|")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.values(person).join('/')
```

Comment: Note that this is ECMAScript 2017 and is not well supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use lodash function _.toString()

```
console.log( _.toString( Object.values( person ) ) );
==> John,Smith,253 689 4555
```

Check the link below
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#toString

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Smith",
    phone: "253 689 4555"
 }



let personData = ${person.name},${person.surname},${person.phone}
```

With this `` mark and $ dollar sign you will get the result.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Not just code

Answer (score 0):

Just use object.values() and use toString() method

```
Object.values(person).toString()
```