# converting object properties to comma seperated values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I want to convert object properties to comma separated values like following-
Join the elements of an array into a string:

```
var fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":"Orange", "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
var energy = Object.keys(fruits).map(function(k){return fruits[k]}).join(",");
```

The result of energy will be:

```
Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
```

But When I apply like this-

```
 var fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":"null", "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
 var energy = Object.keys(fruits).map(function(k){return fruits[k]}).join(",");
```

The result of energy is like this:

```
Banana,,Apple,Mango
```

And I want result like this-

```
Banana,null,Apple,Mango
```

I have tried these links but No luck found.

[Easy way to turn properties of Javascript object into comma-separated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732123/easy-way-to-turn-properties-of-javascript-object-into-comma-separated-list)

**Updated the Question**

```
var fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":"", "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
var energy = Object.keys(fruits).map(function(k){return fruits[k]}).join(",");
```

The result of energy is like this:

```
Banana,,Apple,Mango
```

I want result like this-

```
 Banana,null,Apple,Mango
```

Comment: Is it `"null"` or `null` ? ( and you may use `Object.values(fruits)` ...)

Comment: [It works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/wcos28pg/1/)

Comment: If it’s actually `null` – `return String(fruits[k])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert key-value pair object into an array of values in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411208/how-to-convert-key-value-pair-object-into-an-array-of-values-in-es6)

Comment: It works fine, cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. Please Check [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) [Killer Death](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7694012/killer-death)

Comment: You have a square bracket at the end.

Comment: That is edit problem.[Killer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7694012/killer-death)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Object.values` would be easier.

```js
// for "null"
var fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":"null", "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
var energy = Object.values(fruits).join(",");
console.log(energy);

// for null
var fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":null, "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
var energy = Object.values(fruits).map(String).join(",");
console.log(energy);

// for ""
var fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":"", "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
var energy = Object.values(fruits).map(v=>v===""?"null":String(v)).join(",");
console.log(energy);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":"", "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
var energy = Object.keys(fruits).map(function(k){
    if(fruits [k] ==="") return "null";
    return fruits [k]        
    }).join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

about `join()` ,not show value `null` as string `"null"`, you can check it in `map()` same as below :

```js
const fruits = {"f1":"Banana", "f2":"", "f3":"Apple","f4":"Mango"};
const energy = Object.values(fruits).map(function(value){
  return !value ? "null" : value;
}).join(",");
console.log(energy);
```