# How to get all values of a Javascript Object by its keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a Javascript object with some keys and values:

```
var obj = { 
    "key1" : "val1", 
    "key2" : "val2", 
    "key3" : "val3", 
    "key4" : ""
}
```

I want to iterate all keys and retrieving all values.

I tried 2 ways:

1) Using for(var key in keys)

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var key in keys) {
    // ...
}
```

The problem with this solution is that keys object is an array, so I have to use obj[keys[key]]].
Not very pretty.

Furthermore, inspecting "key4", the return value is "0" instead of "" (empty).

2) Using forEach

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    // ...
});
```

The problem in this case is that if I try to do:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    obj[key];  // <- obj is undefined !!
});
```

The "obj" variable is undefined in the foreach!

What's the best way to iterate in all keys for retrieving all values?

Thanks

Comment: @PranavCBalan the index is second argument https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Answer (score 10):

Just use `for in`.

```
var obj = { 
  "key1" : "val1", 
  "key2" : "val2", 
  "key3" : "val3", 
  "key4" : ""
};

for (var key in obj) {

  console.log(key); // key1 and etc...
  console.log(obj[key]); // val1 and etc...
}
```

Comment: Note that this is dangerous, as T.J. Crowder says, as it will also iterate over any inherited properties. For example, it will iterate five times instead of four if you do `Object.prototype.foo = "bar"`.

Comment: You could secure this `for in` loop with `Object.hasOwnProperty()`, which checks if a given property is not inherited.

Answer (score 7):

In your first example, you're using `for-in` to loop through an array, which is not generally a good idea. To loop through arrays, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) has lots of options for you.

If you want to loop through all of an object's keys, use `for-in` on the *object*:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    // ...
}
```

Note that you'll see both the object's *own* properties and also ones it inherits from its prototype. If you just want *own* properties, you could add a guard:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = obj[key];
        // ...
    }
}
```

...or use `Object.keys` (introduced in ES5, in 2009, so not on IE8; there's a shim if you need to support obsolete browsers like IE8):

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    // ...
});
```

In both cases, you'll only get the object's *enumerable* properties. If you need to include *non-enumerable* properties, reach for `getOwnPropertyNames`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    // ...
});
```

That will get the object's own (not inherited) property names, even if non-enumerable, as long as they're strings (which they always are in ES5 and earlier; in ES2015 and later, they're normally strings but can also be `Symbol` instances if you use `Symbol`s).

`getOwnPropertyNames` was also introduced in ES5, but I don't think it can be shimmed, so you can't use it in IE8 or other obsolete browsers.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) may do the job.

**Alternate approach:**

Using ES6, `Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])` will return an array containing all the values.

Answer (score 3):

**Object.values()** will provide an array of the objects property values.

```
 const object1 = {   a: 'somestring',   b: 42,   c: false };


 console.log(Object.values(object1)); // expected output: Array

 ["somestring", 42, false]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you have this problem of obj undefined, it shouldn't happens.
Here it is another way to it, in addition of the other answers.
It's useful only if you don't need filter something and you want just to have an array with all values (and few lines)

```
var values = []
  Object.keys(object)
    .every( (prop) => values.push(object[prop]))
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: code only answers aren't very useful to the community. Please look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I like the first approach much more than the second one, but there is no need to store the keys separately. Let's consider this example:

```
function parseValues(obj, operation) {
    for (key in obj) {
        operation(obj[key], key);
    }
}
```

As you can see we did not need to read the keys. You can use a `function` like this for any purposes. For example:

```
var myObject = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

parseValues(myObject, function(item, key) {
    if (key !== "b") {
        if (item > 1) {
            myObject[key] = item * 2;
        }
    }
});
```

There are literally infinitely many ways you can use this like. In the second approach the `forEach` runs for the keys and not for the object whose keys you are parsing. You need to use `getOwnPropertyNames`, as T.J.Crowther has already pointed out.