# Laravel 5.2 Dynamic dropdown select not populating (javascript)

Tags: javascript, laravel, select

I have two selects country, and information. The `selected_country` variable is passed to getInfo() which queries all rows matching that country and returns the deptname and id. The id is the `option value` in the select and is stored in the database,and `deptname` is the text displayed in the select.  Right now my info dropdown is empty and I am not getting any errors.

```
public function getInfo()
{
    $country = Input::get('selected_country'); 
    $info = Department::where('addressCountry', $country)->orderBy('country')->pluck('deptname', 'id');
    return response()->json($info);

}
```

route

```
Route::get('related-info', ['as' => 'related-info', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getInfo']);
```

Javascript

```
$('#addressCountry').on('change', function (e) {
    var slots = $('#info');
    slots.empty();
    var selected_country = e.target.value;
    $.get("related-info?selected_country=" + selected_country, function (data) {
        slots.empty();
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.slots, function (index, value) {
            slots.append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

Relavent parts of my view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role = "form" method = "POST" action = "{{ url('/register') }}" > {!!csrf_field() !!}

<select class="form-control" name = "addressCountry" id = "addressCountry" ></select >

<select class="form-control" name = "addressProv" id = "addressProv" ></select >

<select id="info" class="form-control" name="info">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Also in my view in the scrips section

```
populateCountries('addressCountry', 'addressProv');
```

The country and state drop downs are populated using a javascript file its too large to paste here
http://pastebin.com/9XUTPEVY

EDIT: After returning a json response in getInfo instead of the view, if I navigate directly to `related-info?selected_country=Ireland` it will show the id and name of each one. If I goto `/register` and select Ireland in the dropdown the dropdown does not populate but the response tab in the network console in firedebug shows the id and name of each. I also changed `console.log(data);` to `alert(data)` the pop up says [object Object] when selecting Ireland.

Here are 3 screenshots of output 
http://imgur.com/a/jEfuu

Answer (score 0):

All seems right except that you return a view instead of a Json object as response.

Try to replace:

```
return view('auth.register', ['info' => $info]);
```

With:

```
return response()->json($info);
```

Comment: I have changed my code but it still doesn't work. If I look at the network console in firedebug the response tab is showing an empty array ([ ]) unlike before it just showed the html code for the page. The countries I tried with all have data in the database.

Comment: With the json response if i navigate directly to `related-info?selected_country=Ireland` it will show the id and name of each one

Answer (score 0):

Change the javascript code to this :

$('#addressCountry').on('change', function (e) {

```
var selected_country = e.target.value;

$.get('related-info?selected_country=' + selected_country, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#deptInfo').empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, subcatObj) {

        $('#info').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.id + '">' + subcatObj.name + '</option>');

    });
});
```

})

I see that when you are going directly to the url, you are going to : related-info?selected_country=Ireland but in javascript, you go to: 
   related-info?**country**=' + selected_country  but I guess you need to go to : related-info?**selected_country**

Comment: Nice catch. But it still doesn't work, but now if I look in my network console the response shows the id and name of each but the dropdown is still not being populated. I also changed `console.log(data);` to `alert(data)` and the alert says [object Object]

Comment: Okay that's good actually. if you get (object,object). that means you need a one more loop and it will work. let me update my answer.

Comment: Can you try now. Also, If it doesnt work can you show me the console.log screenshot. like what array you are getting and what is the name of the object.

Comment: To get the values in the object and to push it in the select method, you need to run a loop like this : for(var key in objects) {
    var value = objects[key];
} http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key

Comment: i have updated my original post with how my code is now can you check if its right. Also in php storm it says `unresolved variable slots` referencing the `data.slots` in the `$.get` function.

Comment: I have posted screen shots in the original post please take a look. Also could you give me an example of how to do the loop i tried and its not working for me

Comment: slots.append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>'); in this i have value.id and value.name. in that i have id and name as a field name or a key in json. My json was in a format like: "id":"23" , "name":"rutne" etc.. but in your case, i think your key and value itself are i. Syntax of "id":"value". I will update the solution. See if it works.

Comment: Also, when passing the data to view from controller. Do it this way return response()->json(array("cities" => $cities ));  this way you will have a syntax for json like {"person": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Person1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Person2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Person3"
  }
]}  try to populate it from this tutorial, it should work. https://developerdan77.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/dynamically-populate-a-select-element-from-json-data-with-jquery/