# How to combine and display Javascript object array from JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a beginner programmer trying to combine two arrays I got two two different functions, `ebay();` and `etsy();`and displaying the results in a table.

1.etsy() gets its array from jQuery:

```
var b;
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#etsy-search').bind('submit', function() {
        //Making API call to Etsy to retrieve product arrays
        //...
        //Making an ajax call 
            $.ajax({
                url: etsyURL,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.ok) {
                    //assigned variable b to the data.results
                    //alert(b) returns: [object Object],[object Object]
                        b = (data.results);     
                    //start next function
                        ebay(b);

                    }}});return false;})});})(jQuery);
```

2.ebay() retrieves the array from Javascript **and** displays both the array

```
    ebay(b){
    //Making API call to Ebay to retrieve product arrays
    //...
                            //function to retrieve ebay arrays
                            function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
                                //assigns var items the result array
var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
                              //assigned variable a to the items
                              //alert(a) returns: [object Object][object Object]
                                var a = (items);
                                   //combine two arrays together
                                    var result=a.concat(b);
    //alert(result) returns: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]                

                            //get all properties values of a Javascript Object
                            //source stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key
                            var keys = Object.keys(result);

                                //keys.length = 5
                                for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                                    var val = result[keys[i]];

                                    alert(val);
                                   //alert returns: [object Object]

                                   document.write(val[i] + "<br>");
                                   //doesn't return anything

                                   //I want to append the results to table here
                                  }
                            } 
    }
```

Both javascript objects have multiple and different properties:
**Etsy**: `[{"listing_id":123,"title":"etsy","..."}]`
**Ebay**: `[{"itemId":["123"],"title":["ebay"],..,}]`
[Full Ebay and Etsy JSON result shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUriY.jpg)
Question: How do I get the properties value of both arrays, I want to get the "title" property from both and append them into a table.

EDIT: Table format, my end goal here is to take the title, image and price from both arrays.

```
var trHTML = '';
$.each(keys, function(i,item) {
trHTML += '<tr><td>' + '<a href="'
+ item.url +'" target="_blank" style="color: white"><img src="' 
//unsure of the property names such as 'image'
                                + image + '" border="0"></a></td><td>' 
                                + title + '</td><td>' 
                                + price + '</td></tr>';
})
$('#result-table').append(trHTML);
```

[I am able to append the array seperately, the table format and names are as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIOmD.jpg)
The names of the properties are different for Etsy and Ebay
[image]

Comment: How do you intend to deal with the other properties in the table? Would help to see an intended table layout. In principle I would use `$.each(array, function...` in conjunction with directly accessing the properties, but be careful as there are objects mixed with arrays so to access your ebay title it's `var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item[0].title`, note the last `[0]` I imagine this counts up if there's more than one item so this is where I'd apply `$.each(...`

Comment: please show us your table structure.

Comment: I have added my table structure ! along some additional information I don't really know if it will be useful