# How to push nested Objects into individual elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

The following API returns some JSON data:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=bananas

I am trying to push the properties (also objects) of the Pages object into a single array. Each object should be its own element in the array.

For example `query.pages` should be pushed into an array like `[38940{}, 284306{}, ...]`

Im doing this so that I can run through the array using ForEach and populate the DOM with the required data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is a not a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix ***your code*** when it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is all you need if you have ES6:

```
var pages = Object.values(response.query.pages);
```

Or you can use this variant to get it work in older browsers:

```
var pages = Object.keys(response.query.pages).map(function (key) {
    return response.query.pages[key];
});
```

More detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16643074/2965158).

Answer (score -3):

```
// result is the json from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=bananas

const singleArray = Object.keys(result.query.pages).reduce((acc, id) => {
  acc.push(result.query.pages[id]);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks @topheman. Using keys on the object is exactly what I am after.