# Create an array from first element of an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, typescript

Let's say we have this array

```
[{name:string,address:string,tel:string},{name:string, address:string, tel:string}]
```

- Each objects in the array are of the same type
- And I want to extract the same attribut trom each object

How can I create this array from the objects contain in the first array ?

```
[name:string, name:string]
```

I'm still new to javascript/typescript I'm trying to find an efficient way to do it

any idea ?

Comment: What is `{a1,a2,a3}`? This is not an array. Is that a `Set` object?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I've simplified the notation, `{a1,a2,a3}` is just a json object where `a1` can be any premitive type. I've seen Map and it seems like doing the same as using forEach or a simple while

Comment: Can you post an example object? becuse your curren description is impossible. You cant assign values without keys to object. { a : 1 } = great. {1}   = not that much.

Comment: I editted the example with types but is does not change the problem I think, the objects are simple json objects ^^"

Answer (score 2):

The elements in the Object do **not** have any order. But the keys of each value have. So you can access the first [key in the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and use it to get the wanted value.

Like so:

```
let arrOfObjects = [
     {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
     {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}
];
let newArr = arrOfObjects.map( item => item[Object.keys(item)[0]]); // [1,4]
```

Or, in your case, if you want only the first name of each person (regardless of order of keys in the object) a better way to do it is like so:

```
let personArr = [
    {name: "Dan",  address: "here",  phon: "123"},
    {name: "Dany", address: "there", phon: "456"}
];

 let namesArr = arrOfObjects.map( item => item.name);  //  ["Dan", "Dany"]
```

Comment: outputs [1,4].  What if you want all the values from the object ? Do you not need a loop then?

Comment: You can find the way to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key#answer-16643074

Answer (score 0):

```
let m = [];
let a = [{'a1' : 1 ,'a2': 2, 'a3': 3},{'b1': A, 'b2': B, 'b3': C}];
let arrLength = a.length;
let objLength = 3;

for(let i = 0; i < objLength; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < arrLength; j++){
        m.push(a[j][Object.keys(a[j])[i]]);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

> [1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"]

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to avoid, if possible

Comment: what are you trying to avoid exactly ? Looping ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find a solution that does not involve loops like that. Although maybe there are no other way to do it :/  also in your example only a1 and b1 should remain in the output. I editted my example, maybe it was not clear enough

Comment: Updated my answer.