# Convert string to array to get values separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string in my jquery variable like this

```
var str = {"xid":"ICAQ2OWE4MjcwYTY=","eci":"05","cavv":"BwABBUCxSrHAA=","status":"A"}
```

How can I convert it into an array to get the values separately? I want to get values like

```
var xid = "ICAQ2OWE4MjcwYTY=";
var eci = "05";
var cavv = "BwABBUCxSrHAA=";
var status = "A";
```

Comment: str is an object, not a string

Comment: Your `str` looks like an object. In case of it is being an object, you can use `Object.keys` to iterate through its key.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key

Comment: What's wrong with just object props  as in `obj.xid`? Why do you need these vars in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use dot notation to access values associated with a key in an object.

```js
var str = {"xid":"ICAQ2OWE4MjcwYTY=","eci":"05","cavv":"BwABBUCxSrHAA=","status":"A"}

var xid = str.xid;
console.log(xid);
```

Comment: I had to parse it first and then use it. `strobj = JSON.parse(str);`
and then use it as `strobj.xid`

Answer (score 4):

You could take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the properties as variables, which works in any scope.

```js
var object = { xid: "ICAQ2OWE4MjcwYTY=", eci:"05", cavv:"BwABBUCxSrHAA=", status:"A" },
    { xid, eci, cavv, status } = object;

console.log(xid);
console.log(eci);
console.log(cavv);
console.log(status);
```

Comment: But that requires you to know each variable name.

Comment: @Zenoo If you don't know the property names, then you should not create the variables in the first place but just keep them in the object.

Comment: @str Well, if you already know the property names, I don't really see a point in asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @Zenoo Me neither. But *not* knowing the properties and creating local variables makes even less sense.

Comment: This is a bit too much for Friday morning :)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over your object with a `for` and populate the `window` object with `window[key] = str[key]`:

```js
var str = {"xid":"ICAQ2OWE4MjcwYTY=","eci":"05","cavv":"BwABBUCxSrHAA=","status":"A"}

for(var key in str){
  window[key] = str[key];
}

console.log(xid);
console.log(eci);
console.log(cavv);
console.log(status);
```

Comment: You should not use `window[key]` as that creates the variables in the *global* scope.

Comment: @str which is exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: No, the OP did not specify that he wants them to be in the global scope. For example, if you use your code inside of a function, it will create the variables outside (i.e. global) of the function.