# How give key object through condition 'if'?

Tags: javascript, object, key

I used websocket to get a channel. Using the condition for the 'event' you need to output to the console the id and the name of the pair.

```
let ChanIds = {};
w.on('message',(msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
        if (msg.event) {
        }
});
```

```
{"event":"subscribed","channel":"ticker","chanId":4,"symbol":"tBTCUSD","pair":"BTCUSD"}"
```

```
 let ChanIds = { 4 : tBTCUSD };
```

Need to give a key to an object

Comment: `let chanIds = {}` then `chanIds[firstObj.chanId] = firstObj.symbol`

Comment: you can try your question also here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/. Maybe it's easier to express yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Comment: can not get key.must use
 w.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('log--', msg);
    if (msg.event) {
    }

    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let chanIds[someObject.chanId] = someObject.symbol`

Comment: ChanIds[msg.chanId] = msg.pair;