# How to make a nested List?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

So in the web app I'm trying to make, there are two types of users: **Teacher** and **Student**

> **Teacher**
>   - Can create classrooms
>   - Can view **Students** who joined his/her classroom/s
>
> **Student**
>   - Can join a classroom/s created by a **Teacher**
>   - Can view the classroom and classmates who joined the same room

For the **Teacher**, I used these codes to create classrooms :

```
function classcreation(q)
{
    var usuid = generateId();
    var myClasses={};
    myClasses.TheClass = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
    myClasses.Teacher = user.displayName;
    myClasses.TeacherID = user.uid;
    myClasses.ClassID = usuid;
    fbclass.child(user.uid).push().set(myClasses);
}
```

and these codes for **Students** to join a classroom

```
function addclass(){
       var addclassID = document.getElementById("classroomID").value;
       var teacherUID =document.getElementById("teachID").value;
       var studentUID = user.uid;
       var studentName = user.displayName;
       var classRef = 
           firebase.database().ref().child('Classes').child(teacherUID);

           classRef.orderByChild("ClassID").equalTo(addclassID)
           .once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            var studentsRef = snapshot.ref.child("MyStudents");
            studentsRef.child(studentUID).set({ Studentname: studentName });
       });
```

These codes right here allows the **Teacher** to view his/her created classroom

```
  var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
        userRef.on('child_added', function(data)
        {
              var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;
              var Studentx = data.val().MyStudents;
              var classD = data.val().ClassID;
              var ul = document.createElement('ul');
              document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);
              var li = document.createElement('li');
              ul.appendChild(li);

              Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key){
              li.innerHTML += '<span onclick="clickDone(this)">'
                              +roomNames[key]+'</span>
                              <ul style="display:none">
                              <li>Class Id : '+classD+'</li>
                              <li>Students : '+Studentx+'</li></ul>';
                });
              });
```

What my **JSON** looks like

```
{
  "Accounts" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "displayName" : "Dodong Advices",
      "email" : "advicenidodong@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Teacher"
    },
    "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
      "displayName" : "Sweet Macaroni",
      "email" : "Sweet@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Student"
    },
    "yJif4ReTxCcGmo682xWSG3L5MKE3" : {
      "displayName" : "Purple Salad",
      "email" : "Purple@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Student"
    }
  },
  "Classes" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "-LMpvlBl3mEazhxaJwqb" : {
        "ClassID" : "6503-3503-6827",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "StackMates"
      },
      "-LMrfIBg8v-hj1k8X2Qf" : {
        "ClassID" : "7583-2402-2757",
        "MyStudents" : {
          "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
            "Studentname" : "Sweet Macaroni"
          }
        },
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "asdasd"
      },
      "-LMrfMV1aw3YNA0PfooR" : {
        "ClassID" : "8083-2712-3347",
        "MyStudents" : {
          "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
            "Studentname" : "Sweet Macaroni"
          },
          "yJif4ReTxCcGmo682xWSG3L5MKE3" : {
            "Studentname" : "Purple Salad"
          }
        },
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "Trial"
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Based on the JSON we can see that we have 3 users. Purple Salad, Sweet Macaroni (**both are students**) and a **Teacher** named Dodong Advices.

So Dodong Advices have 3 classrooms: **StackMates**, **asdasd** and **Trial**

In the class **StackMates**, Dodong Advices doesn't have a student but in the class **asdasd** he has one, named Sweet Macaroni and 2 students in the class **Trial**

The codes below allows user **Dodong Advices** to view the classrooms he created.

```
  li.innerHTML += '<span onclick="clickDone(this)">
                  '+roomNames[key]+'</span> 
                   <ul style="display:none">
                   <li>Class Id : '+classD+'</li>
                   <li>Students : '+Studentx+'</li></ul>';
```

but not the students who joined one of his classrooms.

The image above is the **result**
[image: result]

I tried using this code to show the list of classrooms and the list of students inside each classrooms:

```
  li.innerHTML +='<span onclick="clickDone(this)">'+roomNames[key]+'</span> 
                   <ul style="display:none"><li>Class Id : '+classD+'</li> 
                   <li><span onclick="clickDone(this)">Students : </span>
                   <ul style="display:none"><li>'+Studentx[key]+' </li></li> 
                   </ul>';
```

But it didn't worked. What is the best solution for this? I really need your help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `data.val().MyStudents` you get a JavaScript object. You have to loop over the elements of this object in order to list the different Students.

There are **many** different ways for getting the properties of an object, see [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

For example, you could simply do something like

```
  var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
        userRef.on('child_added', function(data)
        {
              var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;
              var Studentx = data.val().MyStudents;

              var studentRawList = '';
              for (var key in Studentx) {
                  studentRawList += (Studentx[key].Studentname + '/');
              }

              var classD = data.val().ClassID;
              var ul = document.createElement('ul');
              document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);
              var li = document.createElement('li');
              ul.appendChild(li);

              Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key){
              li.innerHTML += '<span onclick="clickDone(this)">'
                              +roomNames[key]+'</span>
                              <ul style="display:none">
                              <li>Class Id : '+classD+'</li>
                              <li>Students : '+studentRawList+'</li></ul>';
                });
              });
```

This is very rudimentary, you should probably work on the format of the `studentRawList` string, but it shows you one possible way.

---

In addition just note that there are several JavaScript frameworks that would allow separating your GUI and your data model (coming from Firebase) and write a cleaner, more maintainable, code. Of course there is a learning curve (sometimes quite a steep one...), but it may worth having a look. For example, see Vue.js, React, Angular or Knockout.js (much easier to learn but with a smaller footprint and less powerful, IMHO),

Comment: Thank you so much for that mr. renaud. I’m going to try it later. It’s almost 4 in the morning here.

Comment: Btw, do i need to add something in the code or just copy and paste it?

Comment: Just copy/paste but, as I said, you will need to fine tune (format the string, check for possible undefined values of Studentx, etc.) It's up to you now! And good night :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciated your help!

Comment: It worked sir! Will I still use the same process if I want a Student to view or see the classes he/she joined and also his/her classmates?