# Removing Object Keys in objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

My data is currently formatted as below

```
{
    music: {
            timestamp: 34953045,
            value: 290348530945
            }, 
    phone: {
            timestamp: 34953045,
            value: 2349234.23
            }, 
    health: {
            timestamp: 34953045,
            value: 2938.2039
            }
}
```

However I would like to transform my data to

```
[
    {
        timestamp: 34953045,
        value: 290348530945
    }, 
    {
        timestamp: 34953045,
        value: 2349234.23
    }, 
    {
        timestamp: 34953045,
        value: 2938.2039
    }
]
```

I want to fill rows in an mui-datatable but can't seem to be able to get this to work.

Comment: your data in your first code-block isn't valid. Did you mean to use an object (`{}`) instead of an array (`[]`)?

Comment: Yes, correct now.

Comment: You can use `Object.values(data)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all properties values of a JavaScript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `Object.values()`

```js
var data = {
    music: {
      timestamp: 34953045,
      value: 290348530945
    }, 
    phone: {
      timestamp: 34953045,
      value: 2349234.23
    }, 
    health: {
      timestamp: 34953045,
      value: 2938.2039
    }
}

data = Object.values(data);
console.log(data);
```