# How to read keys of childs of a reference in firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have a reference to "a" named as 'ref'. And I want to read all the key(name,age and car) of the child of the reference.
If my JSON looks like ths:

{"a":{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null } }

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('a')
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      var valObj = snapshot.val();
      for (var key in valObj) {
        var value = valObj[key];
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
      }
    });
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot):

> Any time you read data from the Database, you receive the data as a
> `DataSnapshot`. A `DataSnapshot` is passed to the event callbacks you
> attach with `on()` or `once()`. **You can extract the contents of the
> snapshot as a JavaScript object by calling the `val()` method.**

We use one of the techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key) to loop over all the properties of the object.

---

If you know the names of the properties you want to get, you can do, for example:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('a')
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      var valObj = snapshot.val();
      console.log(valObj.name);
      console.log(valObj.car);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('a').on("child_added", snap => {
 });
```