# javascript looping and deleting object properties

Tags: javascript

I have an object with various properties. The name of the object is a global variable but the properties are changed at runtime by methods. Some methods add properties to the object. I'd like to add a method that loops through this object and removes all of its properties that are either null or empty. I could check each property by specifying its name and checking its state but if I add properties later, I'd have to update this cleanup method too. How can I loop through the properties of an object without know the name of the properties first.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: Looping over an object is simple, a `for in` loop, but what do you mean by empty? How do you decide if a value is empty? Do you mean like an empty array (length === 0) or empty object (no properties)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Iteration over an object is simple - the `for in` loop:

```
for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //Now, object[key] is the current value
        if (object[key] === null || isEmpty(object[key]))
            delete object[key];
    }
}
```

`isEmpty` doesn't exist, you have to define it or replace it with something more meaningful, I couldn't understand what you meant by empty in your question.

I use `object.hasOwnProperty` because objects inherit things from `Object.prototype` and possibly other places (arrays for example inherit from `Array.prototype`, which inherits from `Object.prototype`). So:

```
object.toString; //function toString() { [native code] }
```

But, `object.toString` actually refers to `Object.prototype.toString` - it isn't really in your object, but when you type `object.toString`, the interpreter sees that there's no `object.toString`, so it checks up the prototype chain until it finds it.

`hasOwnProperty` checks if a key actually exists on an object:

```
object.hasOwnProperty("toString"); //false
object.foo = "bar";
object.hasOwnProperty("foo"); //true
```

Subscript access to objects is also simple:

```
var object = {foo: "bar"};
object.foo; //"bar"
object["foo"]; //"bar"

var key = "foo";
object[key]; //"bar"
```

Note that whatever is passed to the brackets gets converted to a string. So, for example, you can do this:

```
object[Object.prototype.toString] = "magic";

Object.keys(object); //["function toString() { [native code] }"]
```

In case you're wondering, [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is an ES5 (EcmaScript 5) feature.

Comment: So we could also use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in order to iterate through the object's own properties,right? Something like  `Object.keys(myObj).forEach( function(ownKey){ delete myObj[ownKey] });`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a for each loop to iterate through the object properties.

```
for ( var i in obj ) {
    if ( obj[i] === null ) {
        delete obj[i];
    }
}
```