# How to call a javascript function defined in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
</script>
```

How would I call `test()`?

Edit: I didn't explain this correctly.

I am using the request module of node.js to load an external html file that contains javascript functions:

```
request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {
    }
    else {
        jsdom.env({
            html: body,
            scripts: ["../jquery-1.6.4.min.js"]
        }, function (err, window) {
            var $ = window.jQuery;
```

I'm just looking for the syntax to call a function in 'body'.

Answer (score 5):

So the problem here is that by default, `jsdom.env` does not execute javascript found while processing markup.

You'll need to turn these features on:

```
jsdom.env({
  // ...
  features : {
    FetchExternalResources : ['script'],
    ProcessExternalResources : ['script']
  }
});
```

`FetchExternalResources` controls whether or not jsdom should even bother reaching across the network/disk to collect the bytes of a resource

`ProcessExternalResources` controls whether or fetched scripts are executed

**Note** these names were chosen to encompass other resources types (read: images, css, etc..) which will be added in the future.  The idea here is to provide sane defaults, but have many turnable knobs that affect the behavior of jsdom.

Answer (score 3):

Just call it like any other function on your page, jQuery is a framework and is not needed for running a JS function.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm... probably I'd go with

```
test();
```

But that's not jquery, it's plain old javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 ...

     function (err, window) {
                    var $ = window.jQuery;
                    window.test();

...
```

You could also try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="myscript">
    function test() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
</script>
```

And then:

```
function (err, window) {
                        var $ = window.jQuery;
                        (1,window.eval)( $("#myscript").html() );
                        window.test();
```

Comment: When I try that I get I the following error message: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'test'

Comment: @camden_kid, that's where the function should be defined if it's properly done :/. Like the jQuery you passed as a script is also found there, so are all of the global functions...Are you sure scripts are parsed like this in the html? https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Comment: Esailija - When I write 'body' to a file I can see all the functions defined in scripts. I'm not sure what you mean by 'parsed'. I know I'm getting the correct html data. I just can't work out how to call one of the functions. I used this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) to see what window contained and could not see the function (although I'm grasping at straws here and I'm not sure if the function was meant to be shown).

Comment: @camden_kid, all functions that are declared like you show in the OP can be found in the global object (window). I.E.: `function h(){} window.h();` If the test function is not found in the global object and you can't do `window.test()` then there is an error in jsdom in how it parses script tags' function. I cannot really find any information on whether what you are trying to do is possible at all, in fact.

Comment: Esailija - I think you're right. I now understand what you mean by 'parsed' and I don't think it is, as I should be able to access the functions as you say. Frustrating. BTW I tried your last suggestion and that does not work. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @camden_kid, you can try debugging it... does `$("#myscript").html()` do anything? log it and so on...

Comment: Esailija - console.log($("#myscript").html()) writes out the function definition.