# jsdom: Run a page's javascript functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I've been messing around with jsdom and I can't figure out how to run functions from the html page. For example, I've got a simple page like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello
  </body>
  <script>
    function test() {
      document.write("Bye bye")
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

And I'd like to execute the `test` function from jsdom. How do I go about doing this? I've tried simply calling the function, but node complains that it doesn't exist.

```
jsdom.env({
    url : "http://localhost:8000/test.html",
    features : {
        FetchExternalResources : ['script'],
        ProcessExternalResources : ['script']
    },
    done : function (error, window) {
        test(); // I'd like to do something like this.
        console.log(window.document.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.test()`?

Comment: `window.test()` doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345054/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-defined-in-a-script-tag

Comment: I was missing the `features` part

Answer (score 5):

Well apparently the correct way to do this is with `window.test()`, and the appropriate features:

```
jsdom.env({
    url : "http://localhost:8000/test.html",
    features : {
        FetchExternalResources : ['script'],
        ProcessExternalResources : ['script']
    },
    done : function (error, window) {
        window.test();
        console.log(window.document.innerHTML);
    }
});
```