# Javascript: Type of properties/objects

Tags: javascript, object, types, properties

I have an object which has numerous properties in it. Now I want to access certain properties. For example, object is Car. Car has further properties which are actually objects, for example doors, wheels. Now there can be three, four or five or may be more doors in a car.

Now I want to get a list of object which are doors. Is it possible.

Comment: Yes it's possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you define that an object is a door? Is it an instance of a javascript class? How have you defined this class?

Comment: Here is another example question:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

```
var doors = Object.keys(car).reduce(function (doors, name) {
  var potentialDoor = car[name];
  if (Door.isPrototypeOf(potentialDoor)) {
    doors.push(potentialDoor);
  }
  return doors;
}, []);
```

This makes a broad assumption that a `car` contains properties which are of "class" `Door`. And then returns an array of those properties.

Comment: Worth noting IE8 makes me sad :(

Comment: Hah, but just be happy we can stop noting that nothing works in IE6.

Comment: @JamesMontagne which part of the solution is a problem for IE8?

Comment: @JaredPar `Object.keys`, `Array#reduce`