# How to bind to all custom events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I know it's not possible to bind to all DOM events and I know you can bind to multiple events by supplying a space-separated list.

But is it possible to bind to all custom events (preferably filtered by a wildcard pattern like 'abc*' or name-space)?

**Edit:**
To clarify, I have created some custom widgets that respond to some custom events. For example, they all handle an event called `stepReset` and resets their internal models.

After I've written these, I realized events don't bubble down, so the call `$(body).trigger('stepReset')` basically does nothing. As a result, I am considering adding an umbrella event handler on all widgets' parent elements to propagate all relevant events down.

(I know this is not an elegant solution, but I forgot to tag elements with handlers with a common class, so there's no easy way to use select them all.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With regards to your upcoming edit, you can retrieve *all* bound events by accessing the object's data:

```
var boundEvents = $.data(document, 'events');
```

From here, you can iterate over the resulting object and check each property for your chosen wildcard character, or iterate over that property's array elements and check the `namespace` property of each.

For instance,

```
$.each(boundEvents, function () {
    if (this.indexOf("*"))   // Checks each event name for an asterisk *
        alert(this);

    // alerts the namespace of the first handler bound to this event name
    alert(this[0].namespace); 
});
```

---

<strike>If I understood you correctly,</strike> you can iterate over the special events object to get a list of custom events (including those specified in the jQuery source code).  Here's an ES5 example, you will need to adapt it yourself for older browsers or use [a polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937321/94197) for [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var evts = Object.keys(jQuery.event.special).join(" ");
$("#myDiv").on(evts, function (e) {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: In terms of binding to wildcards or a specific namespace though, I guess he'd have to overload `trigger()` and compare the triggered event to the properties of `jQuery.event.special` manually?

Comment: @Matt: either that or write a custom function to filter the special events at bind time.

Comment: Gotcha, but it seems that custom events [don't get added to `jQuery.event.special`](http://jsfiddle.net/E8ue2/) (in 1.7.1 at least) :(

Comment: @Matt: I think you're confusing triggering with binding.  `jQuery.event.special` is for adding custom event handlers manually, that can be later bound using `bind` or `on`.  Events that haven't been defined there can't be bound to.

Comment: Ahhh, in which case I think we've interpreted the question differently ;). I thought the OP wanted to be able to do things like; http://jsfiddle.net/E8ue2/1/

Comment: @Matt Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Matt: I guess you were right :-) I've updated my answer with a large arrow pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 *just* for **With regards to your upcoming edit**... LOL :P