# View DOM Events (The 'ev' tag thing) in Firefox Developer Tools, How?

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, event-listener

The Inspector of Firefox can [list all event listeners attached to specific DOM node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners) from Firefox 33.

Example page:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <button id="Btn">Test</button>
    <script>
        function TestEventListener(e){
            console.log("handle event");
        }
        var btn = document.querySelector("#Btn");
        if(btn){
            btn.addEventListener("click",TestEventListener,false);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then press F12 and select Inspector, click on the small `ev` tag aside the `<button>`.
[image]

- How did Firefox do that?
- Did Firefox modified `addEventListener` from the beginning?
- Can this be done with native Javascript?

  Like this:

  ```
  function GetDOMEventList(node){
      var listenerFunctionsList = [];
      [Magic Moves]
      return listenerFunctionsList; // [func1, func2, func3...]
  }
  ```

Comment: Firefox would need to store those event listeners somewhere, so that they can be invoked when the event is fired. They might have done it with native code. I think it can be done with js by modifying the addEventListener function, if you want to list the attached listeners.

Comment: According to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046741/get-event-listeners-attached-to-node-using-addeventlistener), Chrome, Safari, and Firebug have a method called `getEventListeners` to do just such.  jQuery also can access any events attached to a node (via jQuery only) but using its `._data` method.

Comment: Review jQuery source code for `jQuery._data(element, "events")`, see [One listener for ALL events in jQuery event namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225987/one-listener-for-all-events-in-jquery-event-namespace/26227362#26227362)

Comment: lots of things can be done in browser core and extensions that can't be done from the window