# JQuery custom event handler with wildcard in the event name

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have been trying to implement a wildcard name within a custom event handler.  A fixed event name is working fine but I would like the handler to handle a number of different scenarios.

```
// this works fine
this.on("custom_event_name", function(e) {
  //some stuff
));
```

This also works

```
// this also works
this.on("event_"+foo, function(e) {
   //some stuff
));
```

What I have been trying to achieve is something similar to how wildcards work in JQuery selectors

```
$("[class^=bar]")
```

Is this possible with event handlers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible, but you can do something very similar by following the answer here: [How to bind to all custom events in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735754/480943)

But there is a different system in place for handling this type of thing that I believe is a much better structure (and more efficient too). What you want to do is pass data to your [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) calls. So you could fire events like this:

```
a.trigger('custom_event', ['foo']);
```

Or this:

```
a.trigger('custom_event', ['bar']);
```

And then you can just set up one event handler where you test against the passed data:

```
this.on('custom_event', function(e, type) {
    if (type === 'foo') {
        //...
    } else if (type === 'bar') {
        //...
    }
});
```

There are other alternatives to handling state besides this (e.g. in the DOM), but putting state in the event names isn't a very viable method.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that works well for me.  Accepted with thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try it the backwoods way, with regular old event signals:

```
$('[name^="beginning"]').click(function(){
    alert('You did it!');
});
```

Comment: He wants the event to be a wildcard, not the element name.