# node.js hash, retrieve keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Just started with Node.JS, maybe this is more a javascript question but, its a thin line.

when i start-up node in CLI i do the following:

```
> x = {num:1, str:'hello', ar:[1,2,3], func:function calc(i){return i *2}}
```

now i can say:

```
> x.num
> x.str
> x.ar        // [1,2,3]
> x.ar.length // 3
> x.ar[0]     // 1
> x.calc(10)
```

thats pretty clear. But now i want know which keys x contains?

```
// this doesn't work 
x.keys   // undefined
x.length // undefined
```

So how do you retrieve the keys of this hash?

And my second question is, what object is x ? how can i get the name of this object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list the properties of a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I was thinking of class names?

Comment: Ah ok... in JavaScript there are no classes, only *constructor functions*, functions that produce objects (any function can be a constructor function though). You can get a reference to that function via `x.constructor`. In your case, the constructor function is `Object` since you create a plain object using an object literal.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks! That clears it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Object.keys(x);` Here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: The answer Felix linked to is much nicer. I'd vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeha, was looking in combination for Node. But its belongs to JS, i agree. Lets close.