# Get number of rows of multidimensional JSON variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a PHP function that returns a multiple-level JSON object in the format

```
var data = {
  1 : { 
    1: { Object },
    2: { Object },
     ...,
     ...
  }, 
  2: {
    1: { Object },
    2: { Object },
    ...,
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to get the length of `data` to initialize a for loop maximum value.  By this, I mean the count of the first level entries.

`data[1].length` returns 22, and `data[2].length` returns 23 via the `console.log` printout.  This is expected, but `data.length` returns undefined.

Is there  a better method than

```
var count = 0;

for (var i=1; i< Number.MAX_VALUE; i++){
  if (typeof data[i] != 'undefined')
    count = i;
}
```

Comment: is there any way you can store your data in an array of objects instead of an object?

Comment: I really don't have control over that part at this time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can control the JSON format, nested arrays seem a better alternative.

If not, you can run something like

```
var length = 0;
for (var i in data) {
    if (isFinite(i) && i > length)
        length = i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How About

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

Comment: Note this may require a polyfill in older browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: I like this answer, but need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of entries in a loop, like this:

```
var length = 0;
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    length++;
  }
}
```

However, if you have control over the returned data, it would probably be easier to return an array instead of an object because the array will already have the length property you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this instead of assigning numeric properties? Arrays will have the length property you wish:

```
var data = [
  [ 
    { Object },
    { Object },
     ...,
     ...
  ], 
  [
    { Object },
    { Object },
    ...,
    ...
  ]
]
```