# get variables of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list the properties of a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

I am making an application that receives a `JSON object` from some services. This object is parsed using `JSON.parse()` and a `JavaScript Object` is returned.

Is there any way possible that I can find out the different `variables` present inside the object?

Example:

```
var some_object
{
    var a: "first"
    var b: "second"
}
```

I need to figure out a way to get names of a and b from this object `some_object`

Are there any predefined methods in JavaScript that do this?

Answer (score 2):

This'll do the trick:

```
for (var key in some_object) { 
    console.log(key, some_object[key]);
}
```

However, you need to initialise your object differently:

```
var some_object = {
    a: "first",  // Note: Comma here,
    b: "second", // And here,
    c: "third"   // But not here, on the last element.
}
```

Result:

```
a first
b second
```

So, in my `for` loop, `key` is the name of the value, and `some_object[key]` is the value itself.

If you already know the variables(' names) in a object, you can access them like this:

```
console.log(some_object.a) // "first";
//or:
console.log(some_object["b"]) // "second";
```

Comment: @user1519703, have you tried this code?

Comment: :I did, it gives undefined!!

Comment: ... How? Did you copy my _exact_ code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var myObject = {
  abc: 14, 
  def: "hello"
}

for (var i in myObject ) { 
  alert("key: " + i + ", value: " + myObject[i]) 
}
```

In this case `i` will iterate over the keys of myObject (`abc` and `def`). With `myObject[i]` you can get the value of the current key in `i`.

Please note thate your object definition is wrong. Instead of

```
var a: "first"
```

you only have to use

```
a: "first"
```

inside objects.

Comment: I suggest you reserve i and j for arrays and some other letter (I use o) for objects

Comment: @micha:Yeah i did try that!
it says undefined!

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried?

Comment: i tried printing the value like:

for(var i in some_Object){
alert(some_Object[i]);
console.log(some_Object[i]);
}

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call `some_object.a` to get `a`, `some_object.b` to get `b`, etc.

You shouldn't be seeing `var` inside an object like that though. Object notation tends to look like this:

```
var some_object = {
    a: "first",
    b: "second"
}
```

Note, no `var` declarations, and a comma is used after every property of the object except the last.

Comment: I actually tried a few things and found an answer:
var no_of_variables = Object.keys(some_object);

thank you everyone for helping!