# how do I map var myKey = "keyP" to functionP.myKey

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, properties, key

As far as I understand the following statements are equal

- object.property
- object["property"]

So, I've been doing some testing and I can't figure out how to make dot notation work correctly for functionP.

I normally use a dump tool *[screendump somewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)* to see what's going on, but it doesn't show the properties for a function it seems.

### Why can I do this

```
alert(functionE());     // returns key and date
alert(functionE.keyE);  // returns key and date

function functionE()
{
    var myKey = "keyE";

    functionE[myKey] = myKey + " +++ " + Date();
    return functionE[myKey];
}
```

### But not this

```
alert(functionP());     // returns key and date
alert(functionP.keyP);  // RETURNS UNDEFINED

function functionP()
{
    var myKey = "keyP";

    functionP.myKey = myKey + " +++ " + Date();
    return functionP.myKey;
}
```

### While I can do this

```
alert(functionT());     // returns key and date
alert(functionT.keyT);  // returns key and date

function functionT()
{
    functionT.keyT = "keyT" + " +++ " + Date();
    return functionT.keyT;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `functionP.myKey` is equivalent to `functionP['myKey']`, not `functionP[myKey]`.

`functionE` is the correct way of doing what you are trying to do.

You could, however, do something like this:

```
function functionX() {
    var key = 'keyP';
    var value = 'foo';

    this.__defineGetter__(key, function() {
        return value;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__(key, function(val) {
        value = val;
    });
}
```

And now it works:

```
> var o = new functionX()
> o.keyP
"foo"
```

`__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` aren't standard JavaScript, so I wouldn't use them. Use `functionE`.