# How to fetch data from JSON object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on SpringMVC. In my controller I create a JSON object and I pass that object to JavaScript. How can I read that object in JavaScript?

My `Map` object

```
Map<String rootNode,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String rootNode,List<String>();
String rootNode = "bhanu";
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
for( int i = 0; i < UserProfile.size; i++ ) { 
    al.add( userProfile.get( i ) );
}
map.put( userProfile, al );
```

At last my `Map` object has this data:

```
{
   "Bhanu":["hari@gmail.com","balu@gmail.com","santha@gmail.com"],
   "root":["bhanu@gmail.com","anu@gmail.com","apar@gmail.com"],
   "hari":["bhanuprasad@gmail.com","sravya@gmail.com","mahesh@gmail.com"],
   "balu":["rama@gmail.com"]
}
```

Now I convert this object with `GSon`:

```
Gson gson = new GSon();
String orgChartUsers = gson.toJson(map);
```

Now I passed this string to JavaScript because this is my Ajax response:

```
function orgUsers( result ) {
    var orgObject = JSON.parse( result );  

         for(var name in result) {
                console.log(name + "=" + result[name]);


               }
}
```

This is working fine but i want to fetch data like this
  first i want to fetch data from **"root"**  in root i have some data when i read root for example i got **bhanu@gmail.com** now i want to fetch the data from **Bhanu** here i got some data like **hari@gmail.com** again i want to fetch data for **hari** like this i want how can i do this any one help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I also recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial to learn the basics about arrays and objects: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your lists will become javascript arrays, so for example you could use:

```
window.alert (orgObject["Bhanu"][0]);
```

which should pop up "hari@gmail.com" given your example data.

See [How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) for details of how to list the keys of your map, should you need this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay.It's working fine but i have one doubt ..by using this output i want to generate orgChart .means for example i want to read orgObject["root"] under root i got some users  "root":["bhanu@gmail.com","anu@gmail.com","apar@gmail.com"] now when i read firstnode bhanu@gmail.com i want to check any json object is there with bhanu if it is there i want to fetch those users how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

The result will be either an object or array.

To iterate over objects you can use the for-in loop

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

To iterate over an array you can use a normal loop:

```
for (var i = 0, ilen = array.length; i < ilen; i += 1) {
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most simple way

```
var result = {"Bhanu":["hari@gmail.com","balu@gmail.com","santha@gmail.com"],"root":["bhanu@gmail.com","anu@gmail.com","apar@gmail.com"],"hari":["bhanuprasad@gmail.com","sravya@gmail.com","mahesh@gmail.com"],"balu":["rama@gmail.com"]};

for(var name in result) {
    console.log(name + "=" + result[name]);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Bhanu=hari@gmail.com,balu@gmail.com,santha@gmail.com
root=bhanu@gmail.com,anu@gmail.com,apar@gmail.com
hari=bhanuprasad@gmail.com,sravya@gmail.com,mahesh@gmail.com
balu=rama@gmail.com
```

Have in mind that the arrays are actually cast to a string. So *result[name]* is actually an array.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay small doubt ..i want to read first what is the data in "root" then remaning data how can i do this..

Comment: You may use *.length* property to find out is it an array or object. For example *result.length*. If it returns something then it is an array.