# Accessing json object using Jquery $.ajax() in a generic way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

I am using jqueryui autocomplete and would like to know if there is a generic way to access the Json object items using $.ajax(). In the example below, the text/value pairs are item.Title and item.AlbumId and it works fine. But I would like to know if there is a way to access it like item[0], item[1]. I tried but it does not work.

```
    // jqueryui autocomplete configuration
    $(element).autocomplete({
                   minLength: minimumTextLength, 
                   source: function (req, response) {    

                       // call $.ajax()
                       $.ajax({
                           url: filterUrl,
                           type: "POST",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: { term: textbox.val() },
                           success: function (data) {
                               response($.map(data, function (item) {

                                   return { label: item.Title, value: item.AlbumId }; 
                               }));
                           }
                       });

                   }
               }); //  end of autocomplete()
```

Comment: You could return a json formated response from the server, then jQuery is able to turn the string into a plain js object .. like `{items:[{"label":"foo", "value":"bar"},...]}`

Comment: the response is a json object

Comment: Then I don't get what you are precisely looking for ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this indirectly, using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).  That way you can reference `item[keys[index]]`:

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
    var keys = Object.keys(item);
    return { label: item[keys[0]], value: item[keys[1]] }; 
}));
```

Note that Object.keys is [only supported by modern browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208020/1001985) (IE9+).  Although, as always, you can [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/atk/1034464) if needed.