# JavaScript: How can I get all the keys and values of an object that begin with a specific string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get all the keys and values of an object that begin with `imageIds`.

My object appears as the following:

```
{
    title: 'fsdfsd',
    titleZh: 'fsdfsd',
    body: 'fsdf',
    bodyZh: 'sdfsdf',
    imageIds: '/uploads/tmp/image-3.png',
    imageIdsZh: '' 
}
```

but I only need the properties `imageIds`, and `imageIdsZh`. However tomorrow, a object might contain `imageIdsBlah` and I would need to pick it up as well. I could remove the first few properties from the object, but then the next object might contain additional properties such as `foo: 'bar'`

Comment: Any thoughts? How about plain old `foreach` + `if`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Maybe your object should be broken up into two objects. You could either have a sub-object on the main one, or you could have the main one inherit from the ones with the `imageIds` properties so that you could simply grab it from the prototype chain.

Comment: note: there is *no* order in an object's properties/methods. Any order perceived in browsers (upon testing) are 'by accident' and *not* per spec! In other words, it often works, but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Some functional style awesomeness:

```js
var data = {
    title: 'fsdfsd',
    titleZh: 'fsdfsd',
    body: 'fsdf',
    bodyZh: 'sdfsdf',
    imageIds: '/uploads/tmp/image-3.png',
    imageIdsZh: '' 
};

var z = Object.keys(data).filter(function(k) {
    return k.indexOf('imageIds') == 0;
}).reduce(function(newData, k) {
    newData[k] = data[k];
    return newData;
}, {});

console.log(z);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ngX4m/

Some minor explanation:

1. We use `Array.prototype.filter()` function to filter out the keys that start with `imageIds2
2. We use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to convert an array of filtered keys into an object of `key-value` pairs. For that we use the initial value of `{}` (an empty object), fill it and return from every execution step.

**UPD**:

A fair update from [@GitaarLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588079/gitaarlab):

> `Object.keys` is ES5, but returns an objects own properties (so no need for `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`)

Comment: @scrblnrd3: any particular question?

Comment: No need of `reduce` here, I think.

Comment: I didn't know about `reduce()` that's awesome :) +1 Cheers.

Comment: You could shorten it a little if you skipped the `.filter()` and just used `.reduce()`.

Comment: @Blue Skies: that's the point - you chain functions each of which independently does its part of the work

Comment: Yeah, I just don't see the benefit of having the condition in one iteration, and the object creation in the next. If they were reusable functions performing more complex tasks, then I could see it.

Comment: @Blue Skies: it's just a normal responsibility separation. You're splitting the task into chunks. So the benefit - is more predictable design.

Comment: OK, I'll buy that explanation. ;-)

Comment: @Blue Skies: that's good because I don't have a better one ;-) It's just more natural for me

Comment: @zerkms: I like it, but see my answer for an alternative when you add more functional goodness alongside what comes with the language.

Comment: I think this is important to add: `Object.keys` is ES5, but returns an objects own properties (*so no need for* `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` ). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys  I wonder, Is this (significantly) faster then other solutions (like the one I answered here)?

Comment: Side note: This does not work in React because it says that 'newData' and 'data' aren't arrays that can be indexed with strings (k is a string). Only int indices allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how large the object is, this may not scale well, but it will work

```
for(key in obj){
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      if(key.indexOf("imageIds")===0){
        //do something
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this precisely answer the question?

Comment: I believe so. Is there something missing?

Comment: Yeah. I believe the answer is not complete.

Comment: If the OP executes the code sample, will it solve his problem?

Comment: Yes, since it will get all of the properties that start with "imageIds"

Answer (score 1):

One also needs to use `hasOwnProperty` in conjunction with the for-in loop (not mentioned in most <s>current</s> previous answers).
Reason is that the for-in loop will also go over the methods/properties that an object would inherit from the proto-type chain (should someone or some library have added custom stuff).

So you are looking for something simple and reliable like this:

```
function fetch(obj, str){
    var key, results = [];
    for(key in obj) obj.hasOwnProperty(key) 
                 && key.indexOf(str) === 0 
                 && results.push([ key, obj[key] ]);
    return results;
}
```

<sub>Note: you could also name this function 'getAllKeysAndValuesStartingWith' (or gakavsw should you work for the army haha).</sub>

**Usage:**

`fetch(object, string)` returns a simple (to loop over) array with found results,
so `var my_results = fetch(testObj, 'imageId');` would give the following output:

```
[ //array of arrays
  ['imageIds', '/uploads/tmp/image-3.png']
, ['imageIdsZh', '']                               /* 
, [key, value]           and more if it finds them */
]
```

Working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/258NM/1/).

Naturally one could also push just the values: `results.push(obj[key])`
I would recommend against returning an object ( `(results[key]=obj[key])` ) since the array is easier to work with in this case.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of the answer from **[@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms)**, I've been working on a **[functional programming library](https://github.com/CrossEye/ramda)** for Javascript.  With the tools from that library, this turns into a (somewhat dense) one-liner:

```
var data = {
    title: 'fsdfsd',
    titleZh: 'fsdfsd',
    body: 'fsdf',
    bodyZh: 'sdfsdf',
    imageIds: '/uploads/tmp/image-3.png',
    imageIdsZh: '' 
};

var x = pick(filter(compose(eq("imageIds"), substring(0,8)), keys(data)), data);
console.log(x);
```

This code is not necessarily any better than what **[@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms)** posted, but it does show off some more of the power of functional abstractions beyond the few that are built into `Array.prototype`.

You can **[see it in action on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/s6Y72/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // json to be searched
var data = {
    title: 'fsdfsd',
    titleZh: 'fsdfsd',
    body: 'fsdf',
    bodyZh: 'sdfsdf',
    imageIds: '/uploads/tmp/image-3.png',
    imageIdsZh: '' 
};


// takes the json 'data' as its 1st parameter
// and the desired 'property' to be searched as the 2nd parameter
// for loop iterates through the entire json
// if the property parameter matches a 'key' name in json e.g. 'imageIds'
// then the value for that property is returned
function fetchProperty (data, property) {
    for(var key in data) {
        if(key === property) {
            return data[key];
        }   
    }
}


// if you wanted to return a bunch of data according to a particular key - value pair
// you could do something like this...
// assume 'array' contains a bunch of jsons 
// newData will hold jsons containing your newly fetched data points
function fetchNewData() {
   var newData = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      var value1 = fetchProperty(array[i], 'imageIds');
      var value2 = fetchProperty(array[i], 'imageIdsZh');
      var value3 = fetchProperty(array[i], 'imageIdsBlah');

      var tempJSON = {};
      tempJSON.imageIds = value1;
      tempJSON.imageIdsZh = value2;
      tempJSON.imageIdsBlah = value3;

      newData.push(tempJSON);
   }
   return newData;
}
```

** I hope this was helpful. If you have any further questions, feel free to reach out. Best of luck. **

Comment: you have hardcoded the key-names which is specifically the asker did not want to, the whole purpose of his question.