# how to extract object name/ object properties

Tags: javascript

Problem :

```
obj = {
 module1 : {type :'int' , value : 100 },
  module2 : {type :'str' , value : 'bio' }
  module3 : {type :'boolean' , value : 'true' }
}
```

how to print the object name/ object property

eg : expected string  " module1  module2  module3"

**Please consider adding a comment when voting down so that the question can be improved. Thanks.**

Comment: try `Object.keys(obj).join(' ')`, but it doesn't guarantee that keys will be in order.

Comment: Someone Down vote in all the answers :)

Comment: Please consider adding a comment when voting down so that the question can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var array = Object.keys(obj);
var string = array.join(' ')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g3u6d4df/)

Note: May need to include the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) for older browsers

Comment: But it doesn't guarantee that keys will be in order.

Comment: @Mritunjay yes... but in practice almost all modern browsers follows the same order

Comment: ok I was not sure that's why I din't answered this, I just given as comment.

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate question [How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)
In modern browsers (IE9+, FF4+, Chrome5+, Opera12+, Safari5+) you can use the built in Object.keys method:

```
var obj = {
    module1 : {type :'int' , value : 100 },
    module2 : {type :'str' , value : 'bio' },
    module3 : {type :'boolean' , value : 'true' }
}
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
```

The above has a full polyfill but a simplified version is:

```
var getKeys = function(myobj){
   var keys = [];
   for(var key in myobj){
      keys.push(key);
   }
   return keys;
}
```

Alternatively replace var getKeys with Object.prototype.keys to allow you to call .keys() on any object. Extending the prototype has some side effects and I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    obj[prop] = 'xxx';
 }
```

Comment: That is setting it. OP wants to get it.#