# Select Key From Nested object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a situation here. I have an object here, Which is nested inside another , here i want to select the key. The object is shown below

```
var x={
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 4,
                "index_time_in_millis": 5,
                "index_current": 0,
                "delete_total": 0,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                "delete_current": 0
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 4,
                "index_time_in_millis": 5,
                "index_current": 0,
                "delete_total": 0,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                "delete_current": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "indices": {
        "get56_name": {
            "primaries": {
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 4,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 5,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "delete_total": 0,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "delete_current": 0
                }
            },
            "total": {
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 4,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 5,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "delete_total": 0,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "delete_current": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I select the key i.e "get56_name" as answer. I dont want the value, I want to select the key how can i get it?

Comment: what do you mean by "I don't want the value?" what will you do with the object then?

Comment: what output you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @NitishKumar:I want get answer as get56_name and assign it to variable. I tried like this x.indices.get(0) and many things like this but none of them are working

Comment: @Juhana:Ya this was the one... Thanks!!

Comment: Ya this Works! Some People Dont Understand, what the question is and just make it as negative!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the first key in array of keys like `"get56_name"`

```
Object.keys(x["indices"])[0]
```

Hope this is what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var your_variable = Object.keys(x.indices)[0];
```