# Accessing nested properties json

Tags: php, jquery, json, nested

I have this json:

```
{"objects":[{"text":{"x":643,"y":71,"width":82,"height":33,"font":"Arial","style":"bold","size":24,"label":"Part A"}},
{"text":{"x":643,"y":116,"width":389,"height":42,"font":"Arial","style":"bold","size":16,"label":"What does \"novel\" mean as it is used in paragraph 8 of \"Turning Down a New Road\"? "}},
{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":170,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"A. old"}},{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":209,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"B. afraid"}},
{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":250,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"C. new"}},
{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":289,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"D. friendly"}}]}
```

I need to get the properties of each element, but I can't get the property of second level, I mean I can´t know if the element is a "text","radiobutton","label", I have no problem with the propeties of third level.

This is my source:

```
                   $.ajax({
                        url: 'generateobject.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET'
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(index, firstLevel) {
                            $.each(firstLevel, function(anotherindex, secondLevel) {
                                alert(secondLevel[0]);//shows [object Object]
                                $.each(secondLevel, function(yetAnotherIndex, thirdLevel) {
                                    //alert(thirdLevel.y+''+thirdLevel.y);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

How do I get the property of second level?

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/208016/1301076

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys(data)` and access the first item. If you run the snippet you should see the types alert as expected:

```js
var data = {"objects":[{"text":{"x":643,"y":71,"width":82,"height":33,"font":"Arial","style":"bold","size":24,"label":"Part A"}},
{"text":{"x":643,"y":116,"width":389,"height":42,"font":"Arial","style":"bold","size":16,"label":"What does \"novel\" mean as it is used in paragraph 8 of \"Turning Down a New Road\"? "}},
{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":170,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"A. old"}},{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":209,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"B. afraid"}},
{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":250,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"C. new"}},
{"radiobutton":{"x":643,"y":289,"width":100,"height":20,"label":"D. friendly"}}]};


$.each(data, function(index, firstLevel) {
  $.each(firstLevel, function(anotherindex, secondLevel) {
    alert(Object.keys(secondLevel)[0]);
    $.each(secondLevel, function(yetAnotherIndex, thirdLevel) {
      //alert(thirdLevel.y+''+thirdLevel.y);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```