# How to get each field data from arrays passed in object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 73.86,
    "lat": 18.52
  },
  "sys": {
    "message": 0.0083,
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1436142797,
    "sunset": 1436190324
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 500,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "light rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 298.644,
    "temp_min": 298.644,
    "temp_max": 298.644,
    "pressure": 948.79,
    "sea_level": 1018.56,
    "grnd_level": 948.79,
    "humidity": 78
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 6.46,
    "deg": 253.501
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 68
  },
  "rain": {
    "3h": 0.225
  },
  "dt": 1436180142,
  "id": 1259229,
  "name": "Pune",
  "cod": 200
}
```

This is the data we get after requesting current weather api for information of given city .
My question is to make a loop which get all information by looping through data and get all values

I don't want to write like this to get data
`data.coord.lon`
`data.weather.id`
 etc etc 
Hope you understand
A loop which go in to object and get each array and extract each  data/property from array

this is the api for reference
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london
have a look

Comment: Please add sample output for above JSON

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: var city = $('#city').val();
        $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city, function (data, status) {
            
            console.log(status);
            $.each(data, function (index,value) {
               
                console.log(index + ": " + value);
               

             

            });
            
         
            

        },"JSON");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean all the properties for the object received, you could use
loop with hasOwnProperty check [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object):

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //key
        //obj[key] value
    }
}
```

You can use it recursively to get internal properties in the same way. 
UPD
Here is the fiddle with recursive solution: http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/xdwqohz1/:

```
function listKeys(data){
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            if((typeof data[key]).toLowerCase() != 'object'){
            console.log(key, data[key])
            } else {
                console.log(key + ': ');
                listKeys(data[key]);
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

[How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: var city = $('#city').val();
        $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city, function (data, status) {
            
            console.log(status);
            $.each(data, function (index,value) {
               
                console.log(index + ": " + value);
                //for (var i = 0 ; i < index.length; i++) {

                //    console.log(index[1]);
                //}

            });
            
         
            

        },"JSON");

Comment: and getting this success
(index):44 coord: [object Object]
(index):44 sys: [object Object]
(index):44 weather: [object Object]
(index):44 base: stations
(index):44 main: [object Object]
(index):44 wind: [object Object]
(index):44 clouds: [object Object]
(index):44 rain: [object Object]
(index):44 dt: 1436184609
(index):44 id: 1259229
(index):44 name: Pune
(index):44 cod: 200

Comment: so what is your question? this comment with code is hard to read actually