# Getting list of attributes inside a JSON

Tags: jsonpath

Is it possible to get list of attributes of a particular JSON map with a JSONPath expression? For example:

`{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}` => `["foo","bar"]`

Comment: Here's a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) that may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames({"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
```

Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) for further information.

Comment: English link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each json object get all the keys and push then into an array. You can try this:

```js
var data=[{"foo": 1, "bar": 2},{"foo1": 1, "bar1": 2}];
var array=[];
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  var item;
   item=Object.keys(value);
  array.push(item);
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```