# Node and NodeFilter functions don't appear in "for .. in window" and "Object.keys(window)"

Tags: javascript

You can try it in your browser (I verified in Chrome 59):

`window.NodeFilter` returns a function

`Object.keys(window).indexOf("NodeFilter")` returns -1

`for (var prop in window) if (prop==="NodeFilter") console.log("yay")` prints nothing

The same is true for `window.Node`.

Why does it happen? How can I get the list of all `window` properties?

Comment: Those properties are non-enumerable. So use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @Xufox thanks a lot!