# Why this array doesnt work map and find?

Tags: javascript

Im debugging a React app, and I have this element here:

[image]

If I try to make a `user.matches[1]` the console returns me the element who is in this position.

But If I try to make a map or a find in this array, the console says "undefined".

[image]

What Im missing here??? I want to make a for on this object. Why I cant?

Comment: Looks like `user.matches` is not an array. Use `Object.entries` etc instead. (Call `Array.isArray` on it, see what happens)

Comment: You can see in the first screenshot already that `user.matches` is an object. If it was an array, the output would be something like `[{...}, {...}]`, not `{1: {...}, 2: {...}}`.

Comment: try and find the type of that, it's not an array im pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @CertianPerformance that is not an array. that is an object. {} not []. What you need to do is count the keys.

This can be found here
[How to list the properties of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

var keys = Object.keys(myObject);

then keys would be an array :)

edit: said object instead of array

Comment: No, `keys` would be an array.

Comment: @FelixKling yup good catch. this is why i should reread things.

Comment: Big problem here. Because I need to map all the values inside this structure. For example, on that structure I have a attribute called "group" . And sometimes I need to filter by this atribute (with a find(k=>k===GROUP_A". 

If I go a Object.keys I have a useless array with: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7". If I do a Object entries, I have other useless array (because I cant make a find) with: (66) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2). 

What to do?

Comment: With being able to get the key length you can now just make an array :) meaning take the length of the keys and push it into an array because you can now loop through and do somearray.push(user.matches[i])