# How to access data of an object inside another object via API?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to explore a little more of [TMDB](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-watch-providers) API and got confused with the way I should access the data coming from one object which is inside another. The URL I linked contains the API I am calling. It has a bunch of objects for each language type containing the watch providers for a certain movie. I am properly calling this API by passing the movie ID I wish to get the said data from, but it either returns undefined or a message error on console claiming the ngFor can not loop inside an object.

My service:

```
  listProviders(movieId: number){
    return this.coreApi.get(`${endpoints.listMovies}/${movieId}/watch/providers`)
  }
```

The component.ts:

```
 watchProviders: any | undefined

  ngOnInit():void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
        this.listProviders(params["id"])
      })
    }, 1000);
  }

  listProviders(movieId: number){
    this.moviesService.listProviders(movieId).subscribe((res) => this.watchProviders = res['results'])
  }
```

How I am passing the data on the HTML:

```
<span *ngFor="let caProvider of watchProviders.CA">{{ caProvider.link }}</span>
```

(Scenario with the said console error)

[image]

I would appreciate any help and tips to achieve the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `watchProviders.CA` is an object rather than an array. You'll either want to drill down further to an actual array, or if you're looking to list the properties of `.CA`, you can use `Object.keys(watchProviders.CA)` to get a list of properties. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) for more.

Comment: Where should I include it though? Inside the subscribe method?