# Get name of a property as a string

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to have such function or design something similar?

```
class Test {
  testProperty: string;
  secondTestProperty: string;
}

function propAsString(input: any) {
  ...
}

let test = new Test();
console.log(propAsString(test.testProperty)); // output 'testProperty'
console.log(propAsString(test.secondTestProperty)); // output 'secondTestProperty'
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? It seems like you would need to have the property name, to access the property name?

Comment: You can find your answer here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object>

Comment: Initial problem I have is comparing two objects, but allowing some of the properties to be ignored. Comparing by obj keys and filtering out ones I want to ignore is not a problem. The problem is to add those undesired keys in an array to later filter.  I do not want to add strings implicitly, because ts compiler would not be able to see them later, and renaming of those properties wont work.

Comment: Sorry but no. Accepted option is no longer recommended by author, other option requires to put properties like string.

Comment: Have you actually read past the first sentence of the accepted answer? To at least "Option 2" in the same accepted answer. Yes, it requires putting the properties as strings, but it gives compile time error if you misspell.

Comment: I did. Compile time error is better than nothing, but its not what I am looking for. Renaming wont work, and you would need to run the code (in my case - visit the page) to encounter it. And having your code littered with string literals is just horrible.

Comment: Well, sometimes the answer is no. You can subscribe to the [corresponding feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579) but it's been out there for nine years.